# Is it possible to disable scrolling on a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` which instantiates a `View`. I'd like to disable both the scrolling of the viewpager and the child buttons momentarily while a search result is returned to the view. I've calling `viewPager.setEnabled(false)` but this doesn't disable it.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Answer (score 379, accepted):

A simple solution is to create your own subclass of `ViewPager` that has a `private boolean` flag, `isPagingEnabled`. Then override the `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods. If `isPagingEnabled` equals true invoke the `super` method, otherwise `return`.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean isPagingEnabled = true;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean b) {
        this.isPagingEnabled = b;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Layout.XML` file replace any `<com.android.support.V4.ViewPager>` tags with `<com.yourpackage.CustomViewPager>` tags.

This code was adapted from this [blog post](http://www.shiftedup.com/2011/08/29/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android).

Comment: greate solution, works fine. If you want to stop swiping like a monkey you can override a  OnPageChangeListener with 

@Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
                break;
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
                mPager.setPagingEnabled(true);
                break;
        }
        // noop
    }

Comment: P.S: In XML, use <yourpkgname.CustomViewPager... instead of <com.android,support.v4.ViewPager...

Comment: to add another similar solution, you can use the library called "JazzyViewPager" : https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager , and just call setPagingEnabled(boolean)

Comment: is it possible to stop scrolling right only? i can scrolling left only

Comment: It is still possible to "scroll" by focusing elements (buttons, etc.) in the pages when using a game controller or keyboard for instance. How to disable that completely? I guess it's another type of event that should be intercepted...

Comment: Yes, you must set the isPagingEnabled variable to false in the CustomViewPager class, change the tag in you layout .xml file to your CustomViewPager class ****AND**** in the .java file that you declare the view pager view, you must import the custom class, replace import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; for import ******.CustomViewPager;

Comment: this will work, we can use this code into our custom view

Comment: Warning "Method 'setPagingEnabled(boolean)' is never used".  Do I even need this code or can I delete it? Will anything be affected negatively if I do?

Comment: Opposed to the `beginFakeDrag()` trick, this custom viewpager completely prevents its touch events. Great solution.

Comment: To prevent "scroll" by focusing elements with a controller or a keyboard just set:

android:focusable="false"

to all your views on the .xml

Answer (score 37):

There is an easy fix for this one:

When you want to disable the viewpager scrolling then:

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

   public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
      return true;
   }
});
```

And when you want to re-enable it then:

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

That will do the trick.

Comment: Almost, but not quite. The touch down still happens, so you can move pages by doing lots of small swipes.

Comment: @Akhil Sekharan Was facing the problem exactly what Flynny is facing when using this answer.. but fortunately don't know how suddenly that error has gone.. :) and worked like a charm !!

Comment: You can do the lots of little swipes so you still have to over    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
ride as per slatons answer

Answer (score 29):

Here is my light weight variant of slayton's answer:

```
public class DeactivatableViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public DeactivatableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DeactivatableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return !isEnabled() || super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return isEnabled() && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

With my code you can disable the paging with `setEnable()`.

Comment: Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will prevent child views to receive input. In most cases this is __not__ the intended behavior.

Answer (score 23):

In my case of using ViewPager 2 alpha 2 the below snippet works

`viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false`

> Ability to disable user input (setUserInputEnabled, isUserInputEnabled)

refer to this for more changes in [viewpager2 1.0.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha02)

Also some changes were made latest version ViewPager 2 alpha 4

> orientation and isUserScrollable attributes are no longer part of SavedState

refer to this for more changes in [viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha04)

Comment: The correct and working Answer for ViewPager2

Answer (score 20):

I found a simple solution.

```
//disable swiping
mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();

//enable swiping
mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
```

Comment: Is this all the code you used? This is not working for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Still can do lots of little swipes.

Comment: This code is not proper bcz It is scrolling very slowly like hanging view

Comment: This may work by luck. Update to ViewPager can break this hack.

Comment: It's still dragging but little by little ( .

Answer (score 17):

I suggest another way to solve to this problem. The idea is wrapping your viewPager by a scrollView, so that when this scrollView is non-scrollable, your viewPager is non-scrollable too.

Here is my XML layout:

```
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

No code needed.

Works fine for me.

Comment: Among all these answers, I feel this is simple and works just fine!!

Comment: OK ... BUT when you have a map as one of the fragment in ViewPager then ... it's a problem

Comment: @ekashking You can move focus to your fragment, so scrolling will affect your map.

Comment: Just one disadvantage, if you have another view pager in one of viewpager's fragment, then that viewpager also not getting swipe

Answer (score 5):

To disable swipe

```
 mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
```

To enable swipe

```
 mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
```

Comment: Scrolling is still possible, its just not fluent anymore. This is basically just worsending the quality without solving the problem.

Comment: duplicated answer

Answer (score 3):

The best solution that worked for me is:

```
public class DeactivatedViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public DeactivatedViewPager (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public DeactivatedViewPager (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After this the scroll will be disabled by touch and then you can still use `setCurrentItem` method to change page.

Comment: Don't know why, but it simply didn't work. The scrolling still happens.

Comment: The `canScrollHorizontally()` method has no effect in current scenario. It is not even called when swipe happens.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer in Kotlin and androidX

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager

class DeactivatedViewPager @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : ViewPager(context, attrs) {

    var isPagingEnabled = true

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this : 
I used `CustomViewPager` 
and next, override scrollTo method
I checked the movement when doing a lot of small swipes, it doesn't scroll to other pages.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } 

    @Override
    public void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
       if(enabled) {
          super.scrollTo(x, y);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the problem that the viewpager was still doing little swipes, but overriding  
`View.scrollTo(int x, int y)` solved this problem for me. 
**Thanks**

Comment: It causes some strange behavior in some cases. Like going to the void and leaving just a blank page '-'

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // stop swipe 
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // stop switching pages
    return false;
}

private void setMyScroller() {
    try {
        Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
        Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
    public MyScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int 
duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
    }
}
}
```

Then in your Layout.XML file replace any ---  com.android.support.V4.ViewPager ---
tags with  ---   com.yourpackage.NonSwipeableViewPager  ---  tags.

Same solution but in Kotlin:

```
class NonSwipeableViewPager constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet?
) : ViewPager(context, attrs) {

    private var isPagingEnabled = true

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return isPagingEnabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
    }

    fun setPagingEnabled(isEnabled: Boolean) {
        isPagingEnabled = isEnabled
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a Kotlin version based on converting this answer from Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437997/8023278

There is no built in way to disable swiping between pages of a ViewPager, what's required is an extension of ViewPager that overrides onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent to prevent the swiping action. To make it more generalised we can add a method setSwipePagingEnabled to enable/disable swiping between pages.

```
class SwipeLockableViewPager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attrs) {
    private var swipeEnabled = false

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return when (swipeEnabled) {
            true -> super.onTouchEvent(event)
            false -> false
        }
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return when (swipeEnabled) {
            true -> super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
            false -> false
        }
    }

    fun setSwipePagingEnabled(swipeEnabled: Boolean) {
        this.swipeEnabled = swipeEnabled
    }
}
```

Then in our layout xml we use our new SwipeLockableViewPager instead of the standard ViewPager

```
<mypackage.SwipeLockableViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Now in our activity/fragment we can call `myViewPager.setSwipePagingEnabled(false)` and users won't be able to swipe between pages

---

UPDATE

As of 2020 we now have [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2). If you [migrate](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) to ViewPager2 there is a built in method to disable swiping: `myViewPager2.isUserInputEnabled = false`

Answer (score 1):

New class ViewPager2 from androidx allows to disable scrolling with method setUserInputEnabled(false)

```
private val pager: ViewPager2 by bindView(R.id.pager)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    pager.isUserInputEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of slayton works fine. 
If you want to stop swiping like a monkey you can override a OnPageChangeListener with

```
@Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) { 
        switch (state) { 
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING: 
                mPager.setPagingEnabled(false); 
                break; 
            case ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE: 
                mPager.setPagingEnabled(true); 
                break; 
        } 
    }
```

So you can only swipe side by side

Comment: I didn't found any method of ViewPager  such as setPagingEnabled(boolean value)

Comment: setPagingEnabled(boolean value)  is to be created by you,becoz there no such method to override.

Comment: Unclear what this `setPagingEnabled()` method does. Please include the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

In viewPager2 by disabling user input, you can prevent the user from swiping horizontally.

```
viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :- (for ViewPager2)

```
viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```