# How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager and below it I have 10 buttons. By clicking on button, for example #4, the pager goes immediately to page #4 by `mPager.setCurrentItem(3);`. But, I want to disable the paging by swiping with finger horizontally. Thus, the paging is done **ONLY** by clicking on the buttons. 
So, how I can disable the swiping with finger?

Comment: How about using [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) in the first place? It will save you a great deal of a headache.

Comment: With ViewPager2, disabling the swipe takes just one line of code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978846/how-to-disable-swiping-in-viewpager2

Answer (score 922, accepted):

You need to subclass `ViewPager`.  `onTouchEvent` has a lot of good things in it that you don't want to change like allowing child views to get touches.  `onInterceptTouchEvent` is what you want to change.  If you look at the code for `ViewPager`, you'll see the comment:

```
    /*
     * This method JUST determines whether we want to intercept the motion.
     * If we return true, onMotionEvent will be called and we do the actual
     * scrolling there.
     */
```

Here's a complete solution:

First, add this class to your `src` folder:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, make sure to use this class instead of the regular `ViewPager`, which you probably specified as `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.  In your layout file, you'll want to specify it with something like:

```
<com.yourcompany.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

This particular example is in a `LinearLayout` and is meant to take up the entire screen, which is why `layout_weight` is 1 and `layout_height` is 0dp.

And **`setMyScroller();`** method is for smooth transition

Comment: @louielouie On a side-note: is there any particular reason, why you chose the `0dp` height/`1` weight solution over `match_parent` height to achieve the full-screen effect? Do you gain performance improvements by doing so?

Comment: @ubuntudroid For the answer to the 0dp height/1 weight, please read this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016781/why-is-0dp-considered-a-performance-enhancement

Comment: Something I missed or someone else would miss: Don't forget to change all ViewPager classes in your Java file to NonSwipeableViewPager. Don't miss any. Great answer!

Comment: This answer does not prevent page swiping when using the keyboard left/right keys (try it in the emulator). May not be a problem for touch devices but with TV and laptops it may be one.

Comment: It worked for me, but I'm including this "static" ViewPager inside another ViewPager and at this page I can't swipe parent ViewPager. How can I get this to work?

Comment: @MarvinLabs In order to prevent paging through keyboard (dpad) you can override `arrowScroll()` in the same way the other methods are overridden (or even the same way as the one suggested in the answer by @Rajul ).

Comment: @MarvinLabs @Thorbear The correct way to disable the page scroll by keyboard is to override the `executeKeyEvent()`.
This is the method that then call `allowScroll()`.

`// Never allow swiping by keyboard LEFT, RIGHT, TAB and SHIFT+TAB keys`
`@Override public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) { return false; }`

Comment: well, this disables also the vertical scrolling... this is bad, if you're using listviews.

Comment: Still scroll page little bit. but if you keep swipe it it will eventually scrolling the page.

Comment: I hope google could have just provided a method to which we supply our interface method on how to handle touches/swiping because I believe it wouldn't hurt?

Comment: @louielouie in your answer you mentioned that you can use onTouchEvent to allow child views to receive touches.Can you make items inside a recyclerview which is the child of a ViewPager swipeable with this method?

Comment: working fine for me. I was having a problem previously that i disable swiping between pager but the editext able to swipe the pager.

Comment: @louielouie how can i use that programical ?

Comment: relying on variable name "mScroller" which can be changed in future is not a good solution.

Comment: Remember use <com.yourcompany.yourproject.NonSwipeableViewPager instead <com.yourcompany.NonSwipeableViewPager to remove of the error: InflateException: Binary XML file line Error inflating class

Comment: First, don't override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` - it will prevent child views to receive input. Second, don't use reflection to get access to private fields (especially in production systems) - you might get problems in the future. Third, read documentation on what result `onTouchEvent()` should return. Forth, to disable 'swipes by little bit' you can try overriding the following method:    
`protected void onScrollChanged(l: Int, t: Int, oldl: Int, oldt: Int) {
            scrollTo(0, 0);
 }`.

Answer (score 488):

The more general extension of `ViewPager` would be to create a `SetPagingEnabled` method so that we can enable and disable paging on the fly.
To enable / disable the swiping, just overide two methods: `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Both will return "false" if the paging was disabled.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    } 
}
```

Then select this instead of the built-in viewpager in XML

```
<mypackage.CustomViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

You just need to call the `setPagingEnabled` method with `false` and users won't be able to swipe to paginate.

Comment: Works perfectly for a view that has several subviews where one uses horizontal scrolling (eg. AChartEngine chart). In my fragment I use a callback to my activity telling it to turn or off the paging depending on if the user touched (ACTION_MOVE) the chart or left it (ACTION_CANCEL). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rajul hey great code snippet.How could this be modified so that it enables paging to the right and paging to the left respectively?

Comment: this is how it should be done - enabled/disable it as you need

Comment: You can simplify your `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` methods with `return enabled && super.onTouchEvent(event);`

Comment: I would also recommend changing the name of field from "enabled" to "swipePageChangeEnabled" or something like that. A month after writing the code you'll hardly remember what "enabled" means, especially when your class is called "CustomViewPager", where it isn't clear what the customization is.
That's also a matter of style, but style matters if you don't want to end up with unsupportable project, that is easier to rewrite completely than to fix it.

Comment: Where do I call setPagingEnabled? ._.

Comment: @Ntikki, you may call `setPagingEnabled()` method after you declare your `ViewPager` like this: `CustomViewPager yourCustomViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.yourCustomViewPager); yourCustomViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false)`

Comment: Why are you returning `false` in `onTouchEvent()` and `onInterceptTouchEvent()`? This way touching the pager titles (or icons) will do the swipe. Return `true` instead to disable also that.

Comment: after I setPagingEnabled() to true, all of the views inside the layout become non click able...it is just like there is a transparent wall overlay on top of the layout

Answer (score 149):

Now we no need to create custom `ViewPager`

A new [**`ViewPager2`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)  name View available in android

> [Vertical orientation support](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#vertical-support)

- `ViewPager2` supports vertical paging in addition to traditional horizontal paging. You can enable vertical paging for a `ViewPager2` element by setting its `android:orientation` attribute

> Using XML

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

> Using code

To disable swiping in `viewpager2` use

```
viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

To enable swiping in `viewpager2` Use

```
viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
```

for more information check this

- [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)
- [ViewPager2 under the Hood](https://helw.net/2019/02/08/viewpager2-under-the-hood/)
- [Hands on With ViewPager2](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/02/07/hands-on-with-viewpager2/)

## UPDATE

- Please check : [Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration)
- For complete example please check this [Use of ViewPager2 in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54643379/7666442)

Comment: It's great, but still looks to be incomplete. I've tried it out with 5 different fragments and after switching between pages one of fragments was kind of lost, i.e. view wasn't neither restored nor re-inflated

Comment: @Toochka sorry to hear that for me it's working fine you can find the sample working code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643817/7666442 if possible please share your code

Comment: @PhaniRithvij please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54643817/7666442 i Have added all details how to use `viewpager2` with `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: @PhaniRithvij its ok let me know if you required any help

Comment: In ViewPager2 you cannot control animation speed. Its defaulted to slow. So ViewPager is better for customization

Answer (score 122):

The simplest way is to `setOnTouchListener` and return `true` for `ViewPager`.

```
mPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {           
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does not work sometimes. I'm using a ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter and several Fragment . After setting OnTouchListener to pager, if I fling left, the UI will still move to left a little bit.

Comment: It works when you add `pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem());` before returning `true`.

Comment: seems to work for me.

To solve some layout glitches i have
`public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }`in my adapter, which forces recreation of pages and maybe solving other problems too.

Comment: This is a PARTLY working solution. Horizontal swipes are handled in some strange way. I tested this with a Drag'n Drop Gridview as part of a ViewPager. When dragging using this solution, dragging from left to right and right to left fails. Personally I find Rajul's approach the best.

Comment: On Android 6 (haven't tested on any other versions yet) if you click and drag left many times you can see the view pager swiping left. It is very funny.

Answer (score 63):

Overriding only `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` is not sufficient in case you have ViewPager itself inside another ViewPager. Child ViewPager would steal horizontal scroll touch events from parent ViewPager unless it is positioned on its first / last page.

To make this setup work properly you need to override also the `canScrollHorizontally` method.

See `LockableViewPager` implementation below.

```
public class LockableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean swipeLocked;

    public LockableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LockableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean getSwipeLocked() {
        return swipeLocked;
    }

    public void setSwipeLocked(boolean swipeLocked) {
        this.swipeLocked = swipeLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return !swipeLocked && super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return !swipeLocked && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
        return !swipeLocked && super.canScrollHorizontally(direction);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well on a ViewPager inside another ViewPager.

Comment: This works for me, also for a ViewPager inside another ViewPager. The correct solution didn't work for me in that case.

Comment: stops animation too when used in tabs.

Comment: If I disable it and suppose I want to enable it then where I can get the event to call setSwipeLocked(false)?

Answer (score 59):

Better to declare it styleable, so you can change its property from xml:

```
private boolean swipeable;

public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyViewPager);
    try {
        swipeable = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyViewPager_swipeable, true);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return swipeable ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return swipeable ? super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
}
```

And in your values/attr.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyViewPager">
  <attr name="swipeable" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

so that you can use it in you layout xml:

```
<mypackage.MyViewPager
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:swipeable="false" />
```

Of course, you can still have a get/set property.

Answer (score 39):

If you are extending from ViewPager, **you must also override `executeKeyEvent`** as indicated previously by @araks

```
@Override
public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
{
    return isPagingEnabled ? super.executeKeyEvent(event) : false;
}
```

Because some devices like the Galaxy Tab 4 10' show these buttons where most devices never show them:

[image: Keyboard buttons]

Comment: Samsung is always screwing things up for Android devs.

Comment: @toobsco42 Samsung is not alone in this instance. SwiftKey (popular keyboard app) allows users to put arrows on their keyboards.

Comment: This is also the fix if you want to stop someone using a keyboard/trackerball from paging your pager.

Answer (score 33):

To disable swipe

```
mViewPager.beginFakeDrag();
```

To enable swipe

```
mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
```

Comment: It's not a good solution because it allows small portions of movement, at least in my app.

Answer (score 16):

I needed to disable swiping on one specific page, and give it a nice rubber-band animation, here's how:

```
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == MANDATORY_PAGE_LOCATION && positionOffset > 0.5) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(MANDATORY_PAGE_LOCATION, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It waits until the next page is partly visible. A code for the next page in `onPageSelected` will be executed. Even the next page will switch. So, this code doesn't do needed.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a `CustomViewPager` with a swiping control:

```
public class ScrollableViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean canScroll = true;
    public ScrollableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public ScrollableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public void setCanScroll(boolean canScroll) {
        this.canScroll = canScroll;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return canScroll && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return canScroll && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

If you set `canScroll` to `true`, this `ViewPager` can be swiping with finger, `false` on the contrary.

I use this in my project, and it works great until now.

Comment: What if i have a button inside the ViewPager and i want the click? this solution stops everything below viewpager to be clicked..

Comment: I did not have the issue that @aimiliano had. I have multiple clickable items in my ViewPager and that all worked fine with this solution. This worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 14):

If your are using ViewPager2 you just have to use:

`viewpager.setUserInputEnabled(false);`

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setuserinputenabled):

> Enable or disable user initiated scrolling. This includes touch input (scroll and fling gestures) and accessibility input. Disabling keyboard input is not yet supported. When user initiated scrolling is disabled, programmatic scrolls through setCurrentItem still work. By default, user initiated scrolling is enabled.

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685871/9026710

Answer (score 12):

I know it's mighty late to post this but here's a tiny hack to achieve your outcome ;)

Simply add a dummy view **below** your viewpager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/dummyView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then add a `OnClickListener` to your `RelativeLayout`.

```
dummyView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dummyView);

dummyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         //Just leave this empty
    }
});
```

Get a bit creative with layouts, their placements and their behaviour and you'll learn to find a way to do absolutely anything that you imagine :)

Good luck!

Comment: An easier way is use `setClickable` instead of `setOnClickListener`, if you don't need to handle `onClick` event.

Comment: wouldn't this also block touches within the viewpager?

Comment: Yes it will. It's the expected behaviour required by OP @androiddeveloper

Comment: @RickGrimesTheCoder I don't think you understood my question. I mean views within the viewpager's fragments. Will they still be touchable?

Comment: No they will not be since the viewpager itself has a click listener. This is only suitable for instances where you don't have interactive elements within the fragments. For example a Welcome ViewPager that changes its fragments dynamically @androiddeveloper

Answer (score 9):

in kotlin

```
viewPagerNavigation.isUserInputEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 8):

I used this class with success. Overriding the **executeKeyEvent** is required to avoid swiping using arrows in some devices or for accessibility:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class ViewPagerNoSwipe extends ViewPager {
    /**
     * Is swipe enabled
     */
    private boolean enabled;

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = false; // By default swiping is disabled
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.enabled ? super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return this.enabled ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean executeKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        return this.enabled ? super.executeKeyEvent(event) : false;
    }

    public void setSwipeEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}
```

And in the **xml** call it like this:

```
<package.path.ViewPagerNoSwipe
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: It works. Only swipe is disabled and clicking on a tab is enabled. AS warns that `performClick()` method is not overriden.

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin, my solution, combining above answers.

```
class CustomViewPager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attrs) {
    var swipeEnabled = false

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return if (swipeEnabled) super.onTouchEvent(ev) else false
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return if (swipeEnabled) super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev) else false
    }

    override fun executeKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return if (swipeEnabled) super.executeKeyEvent(event) else false
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will prevent child views to receive input. In most cases this is not the intended behavior.

Comment: I was able to interact with child views of each fragment.  Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: This did the trick for me - thanks! And yes - I am also able to interact with child views. Swipes, taps, etc.

Answer (score 6):

In kotlin, we can solve this by creating a custom widget inheriting the ViewPager class and adding a flag value for controlling swipe behavior.

**NoSwipePager.kt**

```
class NoSwipePager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : ViewPager(context, attrs) {

    var pagingEnabled: Boolean = false

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (this.pagingEnabled) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event)
        } else false
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (this.pagingEnabled) {
            super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
        } else false
    }
}
```

**In xml**

```xml
<your.package.NoSwipePager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />
```

Disable swiping programmatically. If `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin is applied in **build.gradle**, swiping can be disabled by writing below code.

```
view_pager.pagingEnabled = false
```

Otherwise we can disable swiping using code below:

```
val viewPager : ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
viewPager.pagingEnabled = false
```

Comment: Overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` will prevent child views to receive input. In most cases this is __not__ the intended behavior.

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk Had you observed any problem after implementing this? I had enabled swiping on recycler view items for some actions and it is working fine. So the implementation is working fine in my case.

Comment: Sagar Chapagain: or course, I did. Each of my pages contains custom view, which processes touches in various ways (including scrolling, dragging, single and long taps). Not calling `super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)` results in these views not receiving any input (which is the documented purpose of `onInterceptTouchEvent` method).

Comment: If that is the case you should rather use child fragment and maintain backstack.

Comment: How is this relevant to the current question? Fragments are placed inside some containers (which are __Views__) and their own layout contains __Views__. No matter what content I have inside the ViewPager, I am still dealing with the fact that overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method prevents it (content) from receiving input.

Answer (score 5):

Try overriding and returning true from either [onInterceptTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and/or [onTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), which will consume touch events on the pager.

Comment: wouldn't he want to return `true` to imply the touch event has been handled?

Answer (score 2):

None of the above code is working smoothly.i tried this

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fillViewport="true">

                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy solution to disable swiping at specific page (in this example, page 2):

```
int PAGE = 2;
viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == PAGE) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(PAGE-1, false);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(PAGE, false);
                return  true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write an image gallery with `ImageView`s and `ViewPager`, that supports zoom and pan, see a simple solution described here: [Implementing a zoomable ImageView by Extending the Default ViewPager in Phimpme Android](https://blog.fossasia.org/implementing-a-zoomable-imageview-by-extending-the-default-viewpager-in-phimpme-android/)  (and [Github sample - PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)). This solution doesn't work with `ViewPager` alone.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This worked for me

viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                                             if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                                                 viewPager.setCurrentItem(-1, false);
                                                 return true;
                                             }
                                             else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                                                 viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
                                                 return true;
                                             }
                                             else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                                                 viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
                                                 return true;
                                             }
                                             return true;
                                         }
                                     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
* NonSwipebleViewPager for kotlin
    
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator
import android.widget.Scroller
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import java.lang.reflect.Field


class NonSwipebleViewPager : ViewPager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {
        setMyScroller()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attrs) {
        setMyScroller()
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean { 
        return false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean { 
        return false
    }

    private fun setMyScroller() {
        try {
            val viewpager: Class<*> = ViewPager::class.java
            val scroller: Field = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller")
            scroller.isAccessible = true
            scroller.set(this, MyScroller(context))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    inner class MyScroller(context: Context?) :
        Scroller(context, DecelerateInterpolator()) {
        override fun startScroll(
            startX: Int,
            startY: Int,
            dx: Int,
            dy: Int,
            duration: Int
        ) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want any type of scroll horizontal or vertical from user fingers then you can try -

```
yourViewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```

use "isUserInputEnabled ".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the same for Android in Xamarin, here is a translation to C#

I chose to name the attribute "*ScrollEnabled*". Because iOS just uses the excat same naming. So, you have equal naming across both platforms, makes it easier for developers.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Util;

namespace YourNameSpace.ViewPackage {

    // Need to disable swiping for ViewPager, if user performs Pre DSA and the dsa is not completed yet
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s
    public class CustomViewPager: ViewPager {
        public bool ScrollEnabled;

        public CustomViewPager(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs) {
            this.ScrollEnabled = true;
        }

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            if (this.ScrollEnabled) {
                return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            if (this.ScrollEnabled) {
                return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(e);
            }
            return false;
        }

        // For ViewPager inside another ViewPager
        public override bool CanScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
            return this.ScrollEnabled && base.CanScrollHorizontally(direction);
        }

        // Some devices like the Galaxy Tab 4 10' show swipe buttons where most devices never show them
        // So, you could still swipe through the ViewPager with your keyboard keys
        public override bool ExecuteKeyEvent(KeyEvent evt) {
            return this.ScrollEnabled ? base.ExecuteKeyEvent(evt) : false;
        }
    }
}
```

In .axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <YourNameSpace.ViewPackage.CustomViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my implementation
that if you want to disable the swipe animation you can you use the swipeListener left and right and still want the scroll by finger but without animation

1-Override `Viewpager` method `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`

2- create your own `GestureDetector`

3- detect the swipe gesture and use  the `setCurrentItem(item, false)`

**ViewPager**

```
public class ViewPagerNoSwipe extends ViewPager {
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private OnSwipeListener mOnSwipeListener;

    public void setOnSwipeListener(OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener) {
        mOnSwipeListener = onSwipeListener;
    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                                mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public interface OnSwipeListener {

         void onSwipeRight();

        void onSwipeLeft();

        void onSwipeTop();

        void onSwipeBottom();
    }
}
```

the when you are set up the ViewPager set the swipeListener

```
postsPager.setOnSwipeListener(new ViewPagerNoSwipe.OnSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {

              postsPager.setCurrentItem(postsPager.getCurrentItem() + 1,false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {

            postsPager.setCurrentItem(postsPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, false);

            }
             ...
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just customized the viewpager a little and disable swiping easily.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean swipeLocked;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public boolean getSwipeLocked() {
    return swipeLocked;
}

public void setSwipeLocked(boolean swipeLocked) {
    this.swipeLocked = swipeLocked;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return !swipeLocked && super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return !swipeLocked && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return !swipeLocked && super.canScrollHorizontally(direction);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
shareViewPager?.setOnTouchListener(object :View.OnTouchListener{
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
                for (PAGE in 0..shareViewPager.adapter!!.count){
                    if (shareViewPager.currentItem==PAGE){
                        shareViewPager.setCurrentItem(PAGE-1,false)
                        shareViewPager.setCurrentItem(PAGE,false)
                    }}
                return true
            }

        })
```