# ViewPager block forward on page

Tags: android, android-layout

There's a lot of questions and solutions on how to block swipes in an ViewPager.

Example: [Control which directions the ViewPager can be scrolled, dynamically with UI feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270425/control-which-directions-the-viewpager-can-be-scrolled-dynamically-with-ui-feed)

However I would like to only block forward swipe on an specific pages *(I have a form and register button that takes next page programatically)*

Example:
Page 1 -> swipe <- Page 2 -> swipe <- Page 3 (form) -> button -> Page 4

Tried to extend class ViewPager with methods onInterceptTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent but when doing so I can't get the button to work because everything is read as MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE so don't know when to let the event to go thru or when to use return false;

Comment: Roman Nurik's wizard pager sounds like what you're looking for https://github.com/romannurik/Android-WizardPager

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context; import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; import android.util.AttributeSet; import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

 private boolean enabled;  private boolean blockSwipe = false;

 public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  super(context, attrs);  this.enabled = true;  }

 @Override  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  if (this.enabled) {  return super.onTouchEvent(event);  }

 return false;  }

  public void setBlockSwipe(boolean blockSwipe) {  this.blockSwipe = blockSwipe;  }

 @Override  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  if (blockSwipe)  return false;  else  return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);  }

}
```

Comment: you add this class and using viewpager reference ... block swipe just ex viewPager.setBlockSwipe(true);