# Disabling animation in ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I'd like to disable all the animations for the transitions in my custom `ViewPager`.
This view pager contains four tabs -and each tab loads a `Fragment`- and what the view pager does is to switch the tabs: for example first tab is the index, second is map, etc.

The problem is that if, being the first tab chosen, I click on the fourth tab, I can see how the `ViewPager` goes through the second and third tab and stops on the fourth, and I don't want that to happen.

I tried to disable all the animations for this `ViewPager` trying to use a `setAnimation` to `null` every time the user chooses a new tab to be displayed, but it still doesn't work.

Any idea to achieve this, please?
Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I also tried to override `onCreateAnimation` for each `Fragment` but still not working

Comment: You mean you want to remove the swipe gestures capability too, I understand. If so, try to create a new project for 4.0 + in Eclipse, it will let you create an empty project with both swipeable and non-swipeable tabs, check the differences, it's the fastest way and you can see a lot of code.

Comment: well, actually we can't horizontally swipe now, since cliente didn't like it, so I just wanna remove the animations (swiping is already disabled)

Comment: see my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571100/4891063

Answer (score 191, accepted):

I finally found out: the issue can be solved by just calling the `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)` with an extra parameter to `false`, which is the smooth scroll for the `ViewPager`.
After this, the scroll will be done without any smoothing and thus the animations won't be seen.

Comment: @JayVDiyk Example. on Button Click call it like this: `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);`

Comment: Anyone doing this might also be interested in this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13437997/3075340

Comment: Thanks for clarification...I used it with true; thinking that smoothness will remove the hanging. I misused it  .... :(

Comment: Note current implementation of `setCurrentItem(int item)` uses `smoothScroll true` (except on first layout)

Answer (score 55):

Here's another solution:

- Subclass the **ViewPager** (your custom **ViewPager**)
- Override the two **setCurrentItem** methods

Code Snippet:

```
@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
    super.setCurrentItem(item, false);
}
```

By setting **smoothScroll** to **false**, you're disabling the scroll animation.

Comment: Why do we want to subclass `ViewPager` when it already provides this overload?

Comment: @user1032613 because current implementation of  `setCurrentItem(int item)` uses `smoothScroll true` (except on first layout)

Comment: In viewpager2, the viewpager class is final hence it cannot be overrriden.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for disabling the swipe animation even swipe by the user 
here is my implementation

1-Override `Viewpager` method `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`

2- create your own `GestureDetector`

3- detect the swipe gesture and use  the `setCurrentItem(item, false)`

**ViewPager**

```
public class ViewPagerNoSwipe extends ViewPager {
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private OnSwipeListener mOnSwipeListener;

    public void setOnSwipeListener(OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener) {
        mOnSwipeListener = onSwipeListener;
    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                                mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public interface OnSwipeListener {

         void onSwipeRight();

        void onSwipeLeft();

        void onSwipeTop();

        void onSwipeBottom();
    }
}
```

the when you are set up the ViewPager set the swipeListener

```
postsPager.setOnSwipeListener(new ViewPagerNoSwipe.OnSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {

              postsPager.setCurrentItem(postsPager.getCurrentItem() + 1,false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {

            postsPager.setCurrentItem(postsPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, false);

            }
             ...
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by setting smooth scroll to **false** while assigning position to view pager. By this, smooth scroll will not be there + animations will be gone.

```
vpMain.setCurrentItem(position,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tabselected listener, just set the second argument of the
setCurrentItem
to false to disable the smooth scrolling.

```
mBottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener((position, wasSelected) -> {
       
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);

        return true;
    });
```