# Disable ViewPager scrolling animation

Tags: android, animation, scroll, android-viewpager, native

From the code [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html), I have a ViewPager that sets an adapter. Is there any way to disable the scrolling animation so that it just "jumps" to the new page when I swipe? I'm not looking to disable the whole scrolling function in `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent`, just the sliding animation.

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do not know if there is a clean solution. But you can use a trick and undo the standard page transformer with another transformer. The `NoPageTransformer` would look like this:

```
private static class NoPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        if (position < 0) {
            view.setScrollX((int)((float)(view.getWidth()) * position));
        } else if (position > 0) {
            view.setScrollX(-(int) ((float) (view.getWidth()) * -position));
        } else {
            view.setScrollX(0);
        }
    }
}
```

To add it to your ViewPager, call:

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new NoPageTransformer());
```

Will work in SDK version 16 and above.

Comment: Great, this is perfect solution,
Could you please help for vertical viewpage.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin:

```
viewpager.setPageTransformer(false, FadePageTransformer())


inner class FadePageTransformer : ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {
        view.translationX = view.width * -position

        if (position <= -1.0f || position >= 1.0f) {
            view.alpha = 0.0f
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (position == 0.0f) {
            view.alpha = 1.0f
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // position is between -1.0F & 0.0F OR 0.0F & 1.0F
            view.alpha = 1.0f - Math.abs(position)
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In else block you should set View.VISIBLE instead

Answer (score 0):

the accepted answer still have a swipe animation 
I was searching for disabling the swipe animation even swipe by the user 
here is my implementation

1-Override `Viewpager` method `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`

2- create your own `GestureDetector`

3- detect the swipe gesture and use  the `setCurrentItem(item, false)`

**ViewPager**

```
public class ViewPagerNoSwipe extends ViewPager {
    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private OnSwipeListener mOnSwipeListener;

    public void setOnSwipeListener(OnSwipeListener onSwipeListener) {
        mOnSwipeListener = onSwipeListener;
    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

    }

    public ViewPagerNoSwipe(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return false;
    }

    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                                mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        if(mOnSwipeListener!=null)
                            mOnSwipeListener.onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public interface OnSwipeListener {

         void onSwipeRight();

        void onSwipeLeft();

        void onSwipeTop();

        void onSwipeBottom();
    }
}
```

the when you are set up the ViewPager set the swipeListener

```
postsPager.setOnSwipeListener(new ViewPagerNoSwipe.OnSwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {

              postsPager.setCurrentItem(postsPager.getCurrentItem() + 1,false);

            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {

            postsPager.setCurrentItem(postsPager.getCurrentItem() - 1, false);

            }
             ...
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new NoPageTransformer());
```

---

```
private static class NoPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    public void transformPage(@NonNull View view, float position) {
        view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);
        if (position <= -1.0f || position >= 1.0f) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (position == 0.0f) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```