# Vertical ViewPager depth animation or disable scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-view

I have found solution for standard view pager  [Disable ViewPager scrolling animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097369/disable-viewpager-scrolling-animation) 
But my view pager is already transformed to:

```
public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
    int width = view.getWidth();
    int height = view.getHeight();
    if (position < -1) {
        view.setAlpha(0);
    } else if (position <= 1) {
        view.setTranslationY(height * position);
        view.setTranslationX(width * -position);
    }
    else {
        view.setAlpha(0);
    }
}
```

How is it possible to transform further to achieve depth scroll animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new PageTransformer() {

            @Override
            public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
                if (position <= -1.0F) {
                    view.setAlpha(0);
                } else if (position < 0F) {
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                    view.setTranslationX((int) ((float) (view.getWidth()) * -position));
                } else if (position >= 0F) {
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                } else if (position > 1.0F) {
                    view.setAlpha(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

I did it this way. 
Hope it helps some one.