# How to disable sliding animation in Android TabBar with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using a **TabbedPage**, and whenever I select a new Tab, there is a sliding animation. I would like to **disable the sliding animation**.

There is a [Xamarin Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage) that does this, without the sliding animation. How can I replicate this?

**I'm using a custom ToolBar and a TabBar**, and also a FormsAppCompatActivity in my AppActivity.

**The Sample provided by Xamarin isn't**, so I'm not sure how I can disable these animations.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the Native approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25149835/1544047). This can be done with a custom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabsPage), typeof(TabsPageRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class TabsPageRenderer : BadgedTabbedPageRenderer
    {
        ViewPager _viewPager;
        TabLayout _tabLayout;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var v = GetChildAt(i);
                if (v is ViewPager)
                    _viewPager = (ViewPager)v;
                else if (v is TabLayout)
                    _tabLayout = (TabLayout)v;
            }

            _viewPager.SetPageTransformer(true, new NoAnimationPageTransformer());

        }

    }

    public class NoAnimationPageTransformer : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager.IPageTransformer
    {
        public void TransformPage(Android.Views.View view, float position)
        {
            if (position < 0)
            {
                view.ScrollX = (int)((float)(view.Width) * position);
            }
            else if (position > 0)
            {
              view.ScrollX = -(int)((float)(view.Width) * -position);
            }
            else
            {
              view.ScrollX = 0;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Reading your answer doesnt explain where TabsPage came from.