# How to change page without animation in a TabLayout setup with ViewPager?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have `TabLayout` setup with a `ViewPager`. When I select a tab the `ViewPager` scroll to the selected page with animation (showing all the pages in between current page and selected page). I want `ViewPager` to directly jump to the selected page.

I know I can use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false)` to disable `smoothScroll`. But I want to change the default behavior to disable `smoothScroll` effect on `ViewPager`

Here is what I have done.

```
val mSectionsPagerAdapter = SectionsPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

        vp!!.adapter = mSectionsPagerAdapter
        vp!!.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                when (position) {
                    0 -> supportActionBar!!.title = "Page 1"
                    1 -> supportActionBar!!.title = "Page 2"
                    2 -> supportActionBar!!.title = "Page 3"
                    3 -> supportActionBar!!.title = "Page 4"
                }
            }
        })

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the ViewPager and make a custom ViewPager
Please take a look at Toni's answer in this link:
[Disabling animation in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35444397/6797509)