# collapsing bar layout and recyclerview

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

i am implementing collapsingbarlayout and i want my recyclerview inside it. after reading many post i implemted successfully...but the collapsingbarlaouyt isnt collapsing its still at the same position and the recyclerview is working just fine.Recyclerview items are properly scrolling but collapsingbarlayout isnt working.please help

here is my main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.inthecheesefactory.lab.designlibrary.activity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/header"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>






        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="normal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_icon_tint_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_text_color"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_items" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flinging with RecyclerView + AppBarLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923889/flinging-with-recyclerview-appbarlayout)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question. But if someone finds it (like me)

Try to use

```
android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
```

instead

```
ScrollView
```