# How to cancel recyclerView scroll?

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-recyclerview

How to cancel recyclerView scroll?  I don't need let recyclerView to scroll!

I try to do  `recyclerView.setFocusable(false)`, but it doesn't work!

Comment: you can override canScrollHorizontall/Vertically methods in your LayoutManager and return false. Also override onFocusSearchFailed and do nothing there as well.

Comment: thanks @yigit  this work nice

Answer (score 3):

`RecyclerView` has a stopScroll() method to stop a scroll in progress

Comment: @葉志彬 Please mark it as answer if it helps

Comment: thanks your answer, but stopScroll() only stop scroll when recycler view is scrolling. i want set recycerView scroll unable. @Hossein Rashno

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30531092/4497248

Comment: thanks ,override canScrollHorizontall/Vertically methods in your LayoutManager and return false , this work nice