# Forbid scroll recyclerview if focus edittext

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with horizontal scroll. Every item in recyclerview has edittext. When i click on edittext, recyclerview scroll to end. How i can forbid scrolling?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I wonder why does this happen when recyclerView is horizontal, because there is no problem if it's vertical.

Comment: i am getting the same issue, i resolved this issue by requesting focus on edittext in xml but when i scroll the recyclerview it is scrolling irrelevantly

Answer (score 0):

You could set an on focus event listener on your EditText to disable scrolling on focus and enable it again when it goes out of focus.

Something like:

```
edit_Text.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(disabler);
    }else {
        recyclerview.removeOnItemTouchListener(disabler);
    }
   }
 });
```

Where the disabler is an instance of this class (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30531092/2229572)):

```
public class RecyclerViewDisabler implements    RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not work for me. RecylerView scrolling to end, and focus change on first visible element((

Comment: I have tried it but nothing changes, can you go to my post to review it? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802989/keep-state-recyclerview-when-keyboard-open)

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by using two listeners. The first one one disables scrolling while the user touches input field:

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus){
            manager.setScrollEnabled(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Set onFocusChangeListener to every input field of every item of your RecyclerView in onBindViewHolder() method. The second listener enables  scrolling on user touch:

```
private RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener = new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = rv.getLayoutManager();
        if (manager instanceof CustomLinearLayoutManager){
            ((CustomLinearLayoutManager)manager).setScrollEnabled(true);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
};
```

The code for custom LinearLayoutManager, that allows you to enable or disable  scrolling is described in this answer: [How to disable RecyclerView scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling)

The trick is in overriding one method:

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
    return isScrollEnabled && super.canScrollHorizontally();
}
```

And setting the variable isScrollEnabled when you want to enable/disable scrolling behavior:

```
public void setScrollEnabled(boolean flag) {
    this.isScrollEnabled = flag;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but nothing changes, can you go to my post to review it? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64802989/keep-state-recyclerview-when-keyboard-open)