# RecyclerView inside ScrollView, some items are not shown

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-scrollview

I had a RecyclerView in ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--other stuff-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--other stuff-->

</ScrollView>
```

And the `RecyclerView`'s item is a `RelativeLayout`, inside of which there is an `EditText` and other views. The `layout_height` of that `RelativeLayout` and `EditText` is both `wrap_content`. User can input into that `EditText` without any limit of length/lines so that each item's height is different.

Then I found that `getItemCount()` in `Adapter` returns true value but `onBindViewHolder()` is called of wrong times(less than it should be), thus not enough to show all items.

I found that this will happen only if I wrote `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`. But I cannot remove this line. Because if I did so, the `RecyclerView` won't scroll smoothly and is not harmonious with other views inside `ScrollView` and `ScrollView` itself.

This occurs on 6.0 but not on 4.1.

I communicated with Google at this page: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213914 and he told me this is a bug fix for `RecyclerView`. You can visit that page so that you can understand the question and my goal better(There is a small sample project to show the problem there). I don't agree with him even now and I want to solve the problem. Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: try to set 
android:fillViewport="true" in scrollview

Comment: @LucasPaolillo Well, it doesn't help.

Comment: with android:fillViewPort="true", change the linear layout height to match_parent

Comment: @LucasPaolillo Still useless.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I found the solution myself: replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` and keep `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`. I don't know if this is what `NestedScrollView` is made for but it works.

**NOTICE:**

1. `NestedScrollView` is not a child of `ScrollView` but of `FrameLayout`.
2. This solution will also bring some bugs with self-simulated `adjustResize`.

Comment: thanks. worked like a charm. I replaced ScrollView with NestedScrollView and everything is fine now.

Comment: helped me too, thanks,  ```setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);``` is important to keep the smooth scrolling

Comment: Thats not a good solution actually. This has the effect that the RecyclerView doesnt recycle anymore.

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks:)

Comment: @AhmetK Ok So what's the solution ?

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I replaced **LineaLayout** with **RelativeLayout** and it's solved the issue and all items have shown.

Comment: This solved my problem .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
```

In the first step, you need to create NestedScrollView element in XML:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    // RecyclerViews should be located here

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Next, add the below attribute to recyclerView:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Then, the recyclerView will be as following:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

Finally, the whole the layout will be something like below, you can add other materials inside LinearLayout:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />
        // other materials
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Celebrate.............;)

Answer (score 0):

****The best solution is to keep `multiple Views` in a `Single View / View Group` and then keep that one view in the SrcollView.**** ie.

*Format*  -

```
<ScrollView> 
  <Another View>
       <RecyclerView>
       <TextView>
       <And Other Views>
  </Another View>
</ScrollView>
```

Eg.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView           
              android:text="any text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <TextView           
              android:text="any text"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </ScrollView>
```

Another Eg. of ScrollView with multiple Views

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/CategoryItem"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="₹1000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="so\nugh\nos\nghs\nrgh\n
                    sghs\noug\nhro\nghreo\nhgor\ngheroh\ngr\neoh\n
                    og\nhrf\ndhog\n
                    so\nugh\nos\nghs\nrgh\nsghs\noug\nhro\n
                    ghreo\nhgor\ngheroh\ngr\neoh\nog\nhrf\ndhog"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

             </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```