# How to make RecyclerView To Show Only First Two Item and remain item will be visible by view More options

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In My MainActivity there is more than 3 recyclerViews. so  in this case i want to show only first 3-4 items of every List and remaining item will be displayed in click or viewMore Option. 
Here is a Screenshot of one app which  is actually doing the same thing.

[image: ScreenShot] 
and [url of app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nearbuy.nearbuymobile&hl=en)

suppose the list has 10 items, show only first 3 and rest as viewmore option. that option buttion can be setVisibiity but but about show only first 3 cards and stop scroling

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this library here, https://github.com/harishsn/ExpandableListView

Comment: Thankyou Sir for your answer! but this is not expandableListView.@RonakJoshi

Comment: You can setVisibilaty visible and gone by recycle view holder position in your adapter onBind. Think about it and implement the logic.

Comment: suppose the list has 10 items, show only first 3 and rest as viewmore option. that option buttion can be setVisibiity but but about show only first 3 cards and stop scroling. @Farya

Comment: @xbadal: Just load 3 items first. When user click on more than again load list with all items!

Comment: Thats Fine, i implemented it but providing only limited items. and rest with button, now problem is that when its runs on smaller device it becomes Scrollable. how to avoid that @AndiGeeky

Comment: @ xbadal: Define images and font size for smaller device such that it fits in one screen only!

Comment: is there is any way so that we can stop scrolling. or adjust the dimension of card in recyclerview based on screensize.

Comment: @xbadal: Yes you can use small images for mdpi & define small font size in dimens.xml for mdpi or hdpi! You know how to support multiple device right?

Comment: Did you solve this bro..???

Comment: yes! @MustafaShaikh

Comment: Okay @xbadal can you show the snippet i was stuck same problem it will more helpful if you guide..

Comment: Hi @xbadal I'm waiting for your response still you didn't respond

Comment: can you check the date? its way old i don't have any code now! @MustafaShaikh

Comment: Okay but in what way u solve any clue for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- While setting the adapter at first, only put first 3/4 items in your List/ArrayList.
- Upon clicking on a button(or your any click-able view of choice), put all items in your List/ArrayList and then [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data) your recycler view.

Comment: Thats Fine, i implemented it but providing only limited items. and rest with button, now problem is that when its runs on smaller device it becomes Scrollable. how to avoid that @fluffy and AndiGeeky.

Comment: You gotta extend a layout manager to prevent scrolling. See this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling