# Disable RecyclerView scrolling, keep smoothScrollToPosition functionality

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which I want to be scrolled only programmatically with smoothScrollToPosition  command and not from user swipe events. I tried all the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling) post without success.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't yet try it but I think overriding the onTouch will do the trick.
You could do:

```
mRecyclerview.setOnTouchLisntener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

These methods will consume the touch event while doing nothing with it.

EDIT: Noticed you need to keep the click functionality:

```
mRecyclerview.setOnTouchLisntener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: smoothScrollToPosition  doesn't work properly if I use this code

Comment: Thabks for the answer! All is working fine! smoothScrollToPosition also!