# Custom view 'ImageButton' has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick

Tags: java, android, warnings

Well, I know there are some questions regarding this warning, but i still cannot figure out how to get rid of this.
I don't want to implement the `OnTouchListener` interface on class level, because there are many buttons and i prefer to keep every piece of code on his own "space".
I added `performClick()` after `ACTION_UP` case but the warning still persist.

[image]

Thank you

```
send.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.performClick();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear can you elaborate?

Comment: of course, and sorry if didn't explained my issue in a better way.
mi interface implementation with Android Studio 3 keep showing a warning about not overriding performclick. and i'm looking for a solution

Comment: Shar performclick() method

Comment: the method view.performClick() is the original one from view

Answer (score 12):

Your code is OK, if you are sure that your code works like you want, you can just disable this kind of warnings in: **File** -> **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Inspections** -> **Android** -> **Lint** -> **Accessibility** -> **Accessibility in Custom Views**

Comment: Dan, Does this mean that his warning is completely useless?

Comment: @ZdravkoDonev It's not useless, if you don't call performClick, your view's onClickListener won't work.

Answer (score 10):

Basically it suggests that you should subclass `ImageButton` and override its `performClick()` method but it's not worth the hassle just suppress this warning using `@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")` in your method or just disable this warning like I did.

Comment: Where is this suppress annotation supposed to be placed? No matter where I try I still get the lint error.

Comment: Indeed. In Android Studio 3 I just disabled this warning from the settings menu.

Comment: @MatthewPape The warning does not disappear if `setOnTouchListener` is set to its own view. In this case, you can simply override the `performClick` method and the warning will disappear if the annotation is present.

Comment: @MatthewPape above function name where you set those listeners

Answer (score -6):

Change your this line of code

```
View.performClick ();
```

TO

```
send.performClick ();
```

And add this override method at the end of you activity.

```
@Override
public boolean performClick() {
// do what you want
return true;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: i cannot add an override of performClick in my activity because there is no such overridable method.
my activity extends AppCompatActivity