# How to implement accessible drag and drop handles?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, accessibility, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to implement drag and drop sorting with a "drag handle icon" into my `RecyclerView` using an `OnTouchListener` and got this warning:

> Custom view 'ImageView' has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick

This warning occurs when I call `setOnTouchListener` on my "drag handle icon". Since I don't want to simply ignore the accessibility warning, what is the right way to handle it?

Here is the corresponding kotlin code:

```
viewHolder.dragHandle.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
    override fun onTouch(view: View?, touchEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (touchEvent.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            touchHelper?.startDrag(holder)
        }
        return false
     }
 })
```

And here is an image of the list, to better explain my use case:
[image: Example List]

Comment: You may find an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135249/custom-view-imagebutton-has-setontouchlistener-called-on-it-but-does-not-overr