# Block scroll up of recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I prevent a recycler view from scrolling up?

For example: If I have a recycler view with 20 items and scroll to item 10, I need to block the users from scrolling up again but allow them to scroll down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable RecyclerView scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling)

Comment: That disables the scroll in both directions. I need to disable only scroll up.

Comment: simply hack is to remove the items.

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` has a **stopScroll()** method to stop a scroll in progress.

Refer doc: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

[image]