# RecyclerView Inside another RecyclerView with the same layout manager doesn't scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a RecyclerView that scrolls vertically. 
Inside that recyclerView I am inflating CardViews that contain a RecyclerView inside Of them that also displays items vertically. Whenever I want to scroll RecyclerView inside my cards their scroll is being ignored.

I have been told it isn't a good practice to have two recyclers that scroll in the same direction inside each other but I am creating an app with similar functionality to an IOS app and the inner scroll works great on that app.

Comment: try to use a scrollview inside to make things simple

Comment: Also my opinion is this is a bad practice to pur RecyclerView inside other RecyclerView. Maybe you can make the nested RecyclerView horizontally scrolling?

Comment: @MrVasilev Sadly I can't the company I work at want it to scroll the same as the IOS version.

Comment: Don't use a scrollview or similar (that would defeat the behavior of a RecyclerView, which would then stop recycling views and act like a long list of stuff delegating the function of scrolling and inflation to the ScrollView, which knows nothing about recycling); You are going to have to play around with Touch listeners/gesture detectors to decide where to forward the touch/motion events. I never had to do this, but I'd start there.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks, sounds like a good idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable RecyclerView scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531091/how-to-disable-recyclerview-scrolling)