# Disabling ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have used `ViewPager` to view the images by sliding. But the problem is when I zoom the image and swipe it to view, paging is done instead of swiping the zoomed image.

I have tried with `onTouch` and `onIntercept` touch events and also `setPagingEnabled` to false and true. When I zoom the image, the image cuts and the next (or previous) image opens. How and where to enable paging when the image is not zoomed(and disable it when image is zoomed).

Answer (score 0):

check this link [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)
use https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView for zoom 
hope this will solve your problem