# Sliding the top layer of an activity when clicking a button

Tags: android, android-animation

Please, suggest a solution for the following scenario:

> When a user clicks a button, the screen must be slid from right to
>   left and the next screen must be shown. But the background for the
>   both screens is the same (it's an image), and it is not slid, it stays
>   at its place.

What can you suggest? Can I use activities here, or there must be fragments, or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I created an activity and in the `setContentView()` function set a layout with a custom `ViewPager`. In the custom `ViewPager` the `onTouchEvent()` and `onInterceptTouchEvent()` functions are overriden and just return `false`.
The screens are implemented as `Fragment`s. When a button is clicked, the viewPager's `setCurrentItem()` function is called and the corresponding screen is shown (the `viewPager` object is declared static and it can be called from a fragment).
Here is a good example of using `ViewPager`: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html
And this is an example of a custom  view pager, where sliding is disabled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437997/2346046