# How do I properly maintain session state in registration page of an app

Tags: android, session, navigation, registration

In my app I have to implement a registration process represented by four pages. I want to store each page's information in a session so that at the end of the fourth page when I click the register button, all data could be stored in my local database. I have a next button at the end of each page.

When I click the next button the validation for that page would happen and if all valid details entered the app will navigate to the next page.

I have two questions:

1. How do I navigate between the four pages?
2. How can I maintain the session until I reach the fourth page?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a single `Activity` with [NonSwipeableViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9650884/2558461) such that you don't need a session since all the data is stored in the Activity. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19809996/2558461).

Comment: good approach! would do it the same way. Instead of the NonSwipeableViewPager you could just use Fragments and store the Values in the MainActivity from Fragment like this: `((MainActiivty)getActivity()).storeValues(...)`

Comment: I suggested NonSwipeableViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter due to the smoothScroll to allow the actual switch between Fragments. This way I allow the user to return and edit the previous pages