# Lock page fragment in ViewPager android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, progress-bar

How can I lock paging in fragment activity of viewpager for fragment swipe.I'm performing some operations using progressbar in one fragment.While progressing progressbar fragment gets changes because of swipe action.so while progessing progressbar I want to stop swiping.How to do this?is there any solution??

activity.xml file-

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    tools:context=".MainFragmentActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/title"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

fragment activity-

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Context mContext;
    private PagerTitleStrip pt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),mContext);
        mContext=this;
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        pt=(PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);


    }
```

SectionsPagerAdapter-

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    Fragment fragment;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        if(position==0){
            fragment = new SelectItem();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        if(position==1){
            fragment = new culation();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        if(position==2){
                        fragment = new GraphDisplay();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0 :
            return "Select item";
        case 1:
            return "Calculation";
        case 2:
            return "Graph";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try setting clickable to false:

```
mViewPager.setClickable(false);
```

If that works what you can do is create a function in activity to disable swipe event on view pager and call that function in fragment in event of progress bar show and a function to enable it.

Subclass ViewPager and override onTouch event for example:

**EDIT**

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean lock;
    public void lock(){
        lock=true;
    }    
    public void unlock(){
        lock=false;
    }
    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(lock)
        return false;else{
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

reference:
[How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Comment: it's not working.while changing progress page gets swipe

Comment: where should i write this.i don't have any class which extends viewpager.if i put this in MainFragmentActivity class which i have mentioned above i'm getting error for onInterceptTouchEvent

Comment: you can create different class and put it in src and in your xml you can use this class instead of ViewPager. Remove onInterceptTouchEvent if it is giving tou any error b'coz we are handling things in onTouch only.

Comment: i did the same.& onprogress event i call lock() method.but still behaving same.

Comment: I called lock() method onclicklistener of progressbar now it's working 60%

Comment: what do you mean 60%??

Comment: means now it working but not fully..some times page may swipe again while progressing

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple way to do this, with its adapter.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by paul.boldijar on 2/24/2015.
 */
public class SimpleFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Fragment[] fragments;

    private boolean locked = false;
    private int lockedIndex;


    public void setLocked(boolean locked, int page) {
        this.locked = locked;
        lockedIndex = page;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public SimpleFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (locked) return fragments[lockedIndex];
        return fragments[position];

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (locked) return 1;
        return fragments.length;
    }
}
```

If you want to lock your fragment to a page, just call fragment.setLocked(true,page);
Where page is the index of the page you want to lock.

Comment: this should be the most upvoted answer, instead of making a custom viewpager , this is so much more elegant and simple...

Comment: this changes the count and, as I see it, it would yield a very bad user experience when combined with a page indicator. otherwise this is very nice

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution by Paul, I modified it to support displaying titles as well

```
public static class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private Fragment[] fragments;
    private String[] titles;
    private boolean locked = false;
    private int lockedIndex;

    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments, String[] titles) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
        this.titles = titles;
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean locked, int page) {
        this.locked = locked;
        lockedIndex = page;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (locked) return fragments[lockedIndex];
        return fragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (locked) return 1;
        return fragments.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (locked) return titles[lockedIndex];
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

The way I use it is to say

```
Fragment[] fragments = {//Create fragment objects here...};
    String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    MainPagerAdapter adapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, titles);
    adapter.setLocked(true, 0);
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this View:**
https://github.com/mr-sarsarabi/lockableViewPager

It lets you lock the swipe gesture with a method: `viewPager.setSwipeLocked(true);`

Comment: It's better to add an example and explanation, that will benefit OP and future readers.