# Touch Trouble ??

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-button

I have a viewpager, one of its fragment has a button which if you tap produces two more buttons along the side that you can swipe to touch(much like picking up the phone gesture in android).

(b1)----------(b2)---------(b3)

b2 on touching produces b1 and b3

everything is fine, except that when i try to move my finger horizontally, the touch events of the viewpager come into picture and the page swipe happens.

I have been able to make it happen in an activity without viewpager so there is no one to capture the sideways gestures.

I thought of the following options

1. i tried

   getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager).onTouchEvent(event)

inside the onTouch of the button but i get "Exeption Dispatching Input Event" in logcat once i go outside the bounds of button.

2. trying to disable the viewpager touch event, but i havent been able to do that ?
3. Creating a new transparent fragment or activity which can overlay the fragment, but i am unable to dispatch the touchevent to that activity or fragment ?

Please tell me either of them.

1. disabling the viewpager touch event?
2. dispatching the touch to another activity or fragment?
3. If i could create a custom View that has 3 buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily disable the ViewPager's touch by extending the class and returning `false` from its `onInterceptTouch` method. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s). Hopefully, disabling touch there will clear your other error.

Comment: i know that, but I want to temporarily disable the viewpager touch. when the user presses the button, the viewpager should be disabled and on event UP the viewpager should be re-enabled.

Comment: is it possible to dynamically disable the touch on viewpager

Comment: Pass a Boolean to the custom ViewPager? `if (depressed) { return false; } { else` . . . You can use an `onTouchListener` on your buttons which will give you method for `ACTION_UP`/`ACTION_DOWN` so you can set the state of the Boolean properly.

Comment: 1. cant i directly do this: getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewpager).onTouchEvent(new MotionEvent().setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP));

Comment: I think you solution should work. let me check and give up an up.