# Avoid tab got selected in touch event

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have made an application form in android with 3 sections using tabs and viewpager.

According to my requirement tabs must not swipe manually it should be swiped only in next button click event which has some validation to check fields and decide weather it should go to next tab or not? That is have achieved by using [nonswipeableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s) and making blank onTabSelected listioner

but the problem is when I touch to other tab the fragment does not change but that new tab got selected. how to make that tab not to be selected when anyone touch to that tab?[image] for example if anyone select attatchment tab that tab got selected with blue bar indicator and the fragment remain same. fragment remain same is ok but that attachment tab should not be selected in touch event manually, that I want to handle programatically.

How to disable tab selected indicator on touch of tab?

Comment: When there is no use of tab then why you have implemented tabs in your application. You can use buttons or textview for look like tab view and can maintain your behavior what you want to do on click event.

Comment: I used tab just to show them they are currently at this sections. Tabs were good in look but I don't want it's functionality of touch and swipe. That I need to do programatically with validation checking of mendatory fields

Comment: You can make same look a like buttons that's what i am saying.