# got ACTION_CANCEL when moving a TextView

Tags: android, touch-event

The code is as following. I extended a `TextView` and overrided its `onTouchEvent` method. I want to move the whole `TextView`(not the text itself) left and right. 
The following code sort of works, but it only let me move the `TextView` about 0.5 centimeters, and than I got a `ACTION_CANCEL` event. The `TextView` is 204dp wide.
Anyone can give me some clue why this happens? Thank you.

```
 package com.zhangfuwen.tenkhours;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;



/**
 * Created by dean on 2015/6/20.
 */
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
private int mHistoricalX;
public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mHistoricalX = (int)x;
            Log.e("haha", "down.");
            return true;
            //break;
            //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.e("haha", "move.");
            float diff = x - mHistoricalX;
            this.setX( this.getX() + diff);
            invalidate();
            return true;
            //super.onTouchEvent(event);
            //return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //TODO:启动定时器，进行倒计时
            //
            Log.e("haha", "up.");
            diff = x - mHistoricalX;
            this.setX( this.getX() + diff);
            return true;
            //break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            Log.e("haha","outside");
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.e("haha","cancel");
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE:
            Log.e("haha","hover move");
            return true;

            //}
            //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        default:
            Log.e("haha","action is " + Integer.toString(event.getAction()));
            return true;
            //break;


    }
    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed.
My main activity is a ViewPager which is responsible for swipe action.
When I move the TextView inside it, the ViewPager takes possession of the event.
To fix it, I overrided the ViewPager as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s) question.