# Make swipes on one viewpager be set to another one

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout

I have 2 view pagers in a linear layout both taking up same amount of screen. I want to make it so that if a user swipes any where on the screen then the swipe should only be for the lower viewpager. I tried increasing the touch delegate but that didn't work.

Comment: If you want the swipe to work only for the 2nd viewpager why do you even have the first viewpager in place?

Comment: The 2nd viewpager programmatically swipes the 1st viewpager to give it a delay effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're trying to some trippy stuff! I'd suggest making a CustomViewPager class for the 2nd viewpager which can have an instance of the 1st viewPager.

```
    public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private ViewPager firstViewPager;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(firstViewPager!=null){
            firstViewPager.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(firstViewPager!=null){
            firstViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public void setFirstViewPager(ViewPager firstViewPager) {
        this.firstViewPager = firstViewPager;
    } 
}
```

In this you are passing the motion event that you get in the 2nd viewpager's `onTouchEvent` and `onInterceptTouchEvent` to the 1st viewpager. You'd also want to disable the swipe on the 1st viewpager that you could do as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s).

Comment: And since you mentioned `touch delegate` am assuming you're from an iOS background :) Good luck with your Android app!