# How to create a TabLayout without viewPager?

Tags: android

I have created a toolbar with a tabpane(Background, TextStyle, font).
But I followed serval tutorials on the web and all have it with viewPager/slider which i dont want. So how do I create it without implementing viewPager?

So far I know its something to do with this:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use a `ViewPager` without the horizontal swiping enabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

Comment: Or do a fragment replace.

Comment: @DavidArgyleThacker Allright I will look at that, but is it not possible to only use this method: public void onTabSelected?

Comment: @karaokyo could you provide me with an example thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

Comment: This seems like just an anti-pattern for Android.

Comment: @JaredBurrows which is an ani-pattern?

Comment: Creating tabs that aren't swipe-able.

Comment: @JaredBurrows But as you see in my example, that wont work because there is a HorizontalScrollView which should scroll the list and not ending scrolling to "textstyle"

Comment: If you are not swiping, you are clicking. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 17):

Example code:

```
private void onCreateTabLayout() {
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_directions_car_24dp));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_directions_walk_24dp));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_directions_bike_24dp));
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: I m getting    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/TintManager; this error, please suggest

Comment: This is related to not having your supportlibraries up to date

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem my using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9650884/4646951

it did exactly what I wanted, which was deactivate the touch-swiping between my fragments and only allow "clicks" on the tabs