# Dynamically disable click/swipe/tap of a single tab in Android TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Here I have a `TabLayout` and inside that I have `ViewPager` where are 4 tabs and all tabs are static. I needed a blank space in center of `TabLayout` so I added one more tab in `TabLayout`, now I want to disable it, it should not get any clicked, tap or selector should not come on that particular tab as it is showing in image as

[image]

I'm adding custom view this tab as

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View customView = mPagerAdapter.getCustomeView(getActivity(), i);
        mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(customView);
    }
```

I tried to disable clicks etc on this tab as

```
 LinearLayout tabStrip = ((LinearLayout)tabLayout.getChildAt(2));
 tabStrip.setEnabled(false);
```

but it didn't work for me. Can anyone give me a right way to solve this issue?

Comment: it is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702725/disable-tablayout/35123042#35123042

Comment: but I have no condition to block tab layout completely

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(customViewPager);
customViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i <tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++){
            updateTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(i), position == i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});



private void updateTab(TabLayout.Tab tab, boolean isSelected){
  Method method = null;
  try {
      method = TabLayout.Tab.class.getDeclaredMethod("getCustomView", null);
      method.setAccessible(true);

      View tabview = (View) method.invoke(tab, null);
      //disable tabview here for specific tab
     }

      tab.setCustomView(tabview);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```