# How to disable tabs in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
        val receiptDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_receipt_details) as TextView
        val paymentDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_payment_details) as TextView
        val invoiceDetails = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_invoice_details) as TextView
        val summary = headerView.findViewById(R.id.tb_summary) as TextView

        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(0)!!.setCustomView(receiptDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(1)!!.setCustomView(paymentDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(2)!!.setCustomView(invoiceDetails)
        tabLayout!!.getTabAt(3)!!.setCustomView(summary)

        tabLayout!!.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false)
```

> Here I got a null pointer exception when I called **tabLayout!!.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false)**. How can I disable specific tab in Kotlin. Thanks in advance.
>
> logcat

```
12-03 10:03:27.536 7899-7899/com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr, PID: 7899
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr/com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr.NewPaymentActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.salesrep.auxxa.alliontechnologies.auxxasr.NewPaymentActivity.onCreate(NewPaymentActivity.kt:84)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
```

Comment: can you post the logcat

Comment: Hi Manoj,I added logcat .

Comment: register activity in manifest

Comment: registered already

Comment: Possibly duplicate question please check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31702725/disable-tablayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using custom view, you could disable the tab by consuming the touch event:

```
val view = tabLayout.getTabAt(1)!!.customView.parent as View;
view.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
```

Comment: Hi, isEnabled not support to  tabLayout.getTabAt(1)

Comment: @RajithaPerera My apologies, misread your question. I think you could disable the tab by returning true on touch listener, or maybe you could also try `isEnabled = false`  on the parent view.

Comment: One question?  How I enable this tab once I need ?

Comment: Try `view.setOnTouchListener(null)` or `view.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> false }` to re-enable it.

Comment: Thank you Thank you for saving my day

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
(tabLayout!!.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup).getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false)
```

`tabLayout!!.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup` is the `ViewGroup` containing the children views.

Answer (score 0):

declare the activity

```
var touchableList: ArrayList<View>? = ArrayList()
```

disable all tab

```
touchableList = tabLayout?.touchables
touchableList?.forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
```

Enable the tab

```
touchableList?.get(0)?.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score -2):

change From

tabLayout!!.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false)

To

tabLayout!!.getChildAt(1).isEnabled = false

And Activity not register in manifest. register it.