# How to handle TabLayout click before taking user to the next tab?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I have four tabs with `ViewPager` attached to the `OnTabSelected`.
One of the tab contains Form fields, once user make any change I shouldn't let the user move to next tab unless he saves the changes.

(In other words should throw `alert` on `OnTabSelected` instead of taking the user to next tab)

But I cannot control the `TabLayout -> "addOnTabSelectedListener"`

Any help would be great

```
binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
        if (State.isClear()) {
            showNextTab()
        } else {
            showSaveSelectionAlert()
        }
    }

    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
    }

    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
    }
})
```

Comment: is there any button you gave to call that fun ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437997/8011713). The `CustomViewPager` shown there is not allowing any scrolling what so ever unless you specifically allow it by setting `setPagingEnabled` to true. What my idea would be to have `setPagingEnabled` to false until the user has filled out all the fields. If this is the case, paging will be enabled again and therefore the user can swipe to the next tab. Otherwise error messages will appear.

We can extend this further and make it applicable to the `TabLayout` as well. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32104992/8011713) shows you how to disable click of a Tab. The `onTouch` has to be overriden a bit differently though. If all your criteria are met, you should return false - meaning the user can switch the tab. Else display error messages.

**So in short:** Disable paging of ViewPager and tab switching of TabLayout with help of the links I have provided you. Enable it once your criteria are met, else show errors.

Comment: setPagingEnabled(false) didnt stop the paging.
TabLayout onTouch disable worked.

Once the state is dirty I disabled the onTouch which worked, but I have to show a dialog while the user taps on the next tab, which I couldn't do, because we disabled the onTouch Event for the tab. This solution doesn't solve my entire problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isShowNext = true;

if(isShowNext)
{
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
}
else{
   // show alert here
}
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of an explanation how that resolves the OP's problem?