# How do I disable swiping on FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) which uses a TabLayout with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Everything is great, except I need to disable swiping on my second tab, as it uses horizontal scrolling. It's okay if scrolling is disabled for all tabs, but It would be awesome if it were only disabled for the second one.

It looks like for a ViewPager I would override the `onInterceptTouchEvent()` method, but this does not appear to be an option for `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks.

Edit: I only have two fragments, so if FragmentStatePagerAdapter is not appropriate, I'm open to suggestions.

**Edit 2**: the problem of not swiping has been solved. However, I'd still like to know how to prevent swiping for only the 2nd fragment.

Comment: Your example is using a `ViewPager`. There is a difference between the pager and the adapter.

Comment: @karaokyo, thank you. You are completely right. I was confusing the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` with the ViewPager. I used the solution suggested below and it works great. Cheers! http://stackoverflow.com/a/9650884/3165621

Comment: How did you implement onInterceptTouchEvent() ??

Comment: A ViewPagerAdapter can extend a FragmentStateAdapter. This is a totally legit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent` to exclude only the tab index that you want:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(getCurrentItem()){
        case 1:
            return false;
        default:
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch(getCurrentItem()){
        case 1:
            return false;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `getCurrentItem()` was exactly the piece I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any solution for an actual FragmentStatePagerAdapter, for the millions of people that are lead here?

Comment: Hey @behelit I believe you can use FragmentStatePagerAdapter as it is but you will have to chage the ViewPager defined in xml to CustomViewPager. And to achieve this we have to create new class eg.CustomViewPager  extending ViewPager and overide the function. check this to see how to create custom viewpager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656902/disable-swipe-in-fragmentpageradapter-android/41657057#41657057

Comment: Yeah that is entirely wrong. Making a custom class does not allow the use for FragmentStateAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is how this is done:

Here is my FragmentStateAdapter -

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    private val totalTabs: Int,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle,
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = totalTabs

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> RadioFragment()
            1 -> ThingsToDoInTheAreaMapFragment()
            2 -> SavedRadioStationsFragment()
            else -> RadioFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/app_bar_layout" />
```

Here is my implementation of it:

```
binding.viewPager.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(
                supportFragmentManager,
                binding.tabsLayout.tabCount,
                lifecycle
            )
```

Then to disable swiping, add the following line after creating the adapter:

```
binding.viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```