# Viewpager disable swipe Issue when touch on Horizontal Listview inside it

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, horizontallistview

i have been searching solution for this problem since two days but not succeeded yet.I have taken View pager to show details of a List view in my application, When swiped shows the details of next list item. I have the Requirement of Horizontal List view inside view pager single item.Now My problem here is When i want to swipe this Horizontal List view entire View pager item is getting Swiped, i also handled On touch event for my Horizontal List view to disallow the swipe action of View Pager but still View pager is getting swiped.Please help me, below is my code

CustomViewPager.Java

```
import com.devpoint.adapter.HorizontalListView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean scrollDisable = false;


    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) { 
        if(scrollDisable) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    public void disableScroll() {
        scrollDisable = true;
    }

    public void enableScroll() {
        scrollDisable = false;
    }



}
```

And it is my single item of a View Pager Item

details_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollviewid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp" >

            ------------------------

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/cardview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_medium"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="35dp"
                        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/padding_radius" >

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="170dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <com.devpoint.adapter.HorizontalListView
                                android:id="@+id/gridview"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:columnWidth="60dp"
                                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                                android:numColumns="3"
                                android:padding="10dp"
                                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                                android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
                        </TableRow>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



        </ScrollView>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

and i handled touch item for Horizontal Listview Inside Adapter as

```
cardview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View arg0,
                        MotionEvent ev) {
                    switch(ev.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        DetailsViewpagerFragment.viewPager.disableScroll();
                        //enable swiping

                        scrollview.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        DetailsViewpagerFragment.viewPager.disableScroll(); 
                        scrollview.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        DetailsViewpagerFragment.viewPager.enableScroll();
                        scrollview.setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

Note: I am Using Fragments in My Application.Thank You

Any help would be very very very thankfull....

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

Answer (score 2):

I face the same problems as yours. I hope is not too late to answer your question now. The way I solve this:

```
// Declare Variables 
HorizontalListView listView;
ViewPager viewPager;
ScrollView scrollListView;
```

We need below variables to fix this issues. We can call *viewPager* in Fragment.

```
listView = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);
viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
scrollListView = (ScrollView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.your_scrollview_layout_id);
```

Now implement **setOnTouchListener**:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
       {
          // disable swiping of ViewPager
          // disable scrolling of ScrollView
          viewPager.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
          scrollListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
       }
       return false;
    }
});
```

Note**:

(1) This method doesn't need to customise ViewPager class.

(2) Disable ScrollView give me a better scrolling performance in HorizontalListView.

(3) Initially I Implements **setOnTouchListener** to *parent layout* of HorizontalListView (like what you did), but I doesn't get the desired result. After HorizontalListView implements setOnTouchListener, it works well.

Hopefully it's helps others too. ^^v

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code for nonSwipeable viewpager... hopefully it will work for     you**

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

   @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav Singh Maurya.. But when ACTION_MOVEUP from Horizontal Listview ,Viewpager Have to swipe, Will it work?

Comment: @Harikrishna I do not know you have to apply this code and check it.

Comment: I applied the code but it wont works..viewpager completely loses its swipe action but my requirement is while i am swiping horizontal Listview swipe will disable,if not swipe have to work .thanks @Abhinav

Comment: Any Solution for my issue @Abhinav Singh Maurya

Comment: @Harikrishna Sorry I do not have any right now. If I come across any I will definitely post it as answer

Comment: Thank you @Abhinav Singh Maurya