# Regarding to the contradiction of using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

1. My question is in my activity or fragment, there are `TabLayout` and [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). If I was to disable swipe of `ViewPager` by using a class called [NonSwipeableViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s). Then why should I bother to using `ViewPager` right from the start, I could have just use `TabLayout` to add tabs which is much more simpler.
2. What are the other advantages of using `ViewPager` even though the primary function of it which is Creating Swipe Views with Tabs is not needed?
3. Do `Fragment` layout must use framelayout? Which means can I use relative or liner layout instead of framelayout?
4. Last but not least, do I allowed to use `ViewPager` with the swipe disabled?

Comment: how do you display your content?

Comment: @karaokyo In an activity, there are toolbar at top, viewpager at middle, and tablayout at bottom.

Comment: right, so how are you planning on displaying it without the view pager?

Comment: I've found that if you don't want the swipe functionality that it's better to use a frame layout and do the fragment transactions yourself.  I created a tab manager class in order to keep it encapsulated.  It's only a little bit more code than you would have in a fragment pager adapter.

Comment: you also miss out on the tab swap animation if you do a fragment replace

Comment: @karaokyo Actually if not using ViewPage I will create a framelayout to show the fragment

Comment: @DanielNugent Can I continue using ViewPager even if I disable the swipe?