# View pager with fragment which cannot be swiped but only clicked on Tab in android material design

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

When there is scroll view in UI, then the view gets stretched and it overflows and there is a sluggish movement when we swipe. However I do not want it to swipe at all. If there is no scroll, then this behavior is not observed.

I have used code from [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/).

This is the code that I am using.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } }
```

This is the xml layout that I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fillViewport="false" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="126dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="105dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText6" />

            <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText01" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText222"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_marginTop="126dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText33"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginTop="105dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText42"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText61" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText41"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4" />



            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText35" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText011" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText333" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText423" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText431" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText44"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Comment: I have already looked at that question and I have adopted that solution however my problem arises when there is a scrollbar in the view. When there are more items, it starts swiping sluggishly.