# TabLayout without using ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, onclick, android-tablayout

I want to implement a `TabLayout` because it is simple but all the tutorials I have found involve a `ViewPager`.  I just want something like `OnClickListener` where if I click the `Add` icon, it will show a toast that displays "tab 1" and if I click a calendar icon, it will show a toast that displays "tab 2"

I would like to use `TabLayout` because it handles device rotations.

**`Main_activity.java`**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    // Add five tabs.  Three have icons and two have text titles
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.add_live));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.calendar_live));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.group_live));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Send"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Send & Post"));

}

}
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: u may refer here : http://androidexample.com/Tab_Layout_%7C_TabBar_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=103&aaid=125

Comment: I would still use a viewpager for the transition animations personally, but disable the ability for the user to swipe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9650884/1219389

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I found **`addOnTabSelectedListener`**:

```java
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab " + tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab " + tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 2){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab " + tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 3){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab " + tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() == 4){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab " + tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is it possible to pass custom layout for tab in above way without pager?

Comment: yeah you can. .try using. `tabLayout.addView(View)`

Comment: no clue why this was so hard to find an answer to, but thank you very much for posting. On a side note, I also set the tab tags (setTag()) so that I could reference which one was being clicked.

Comment: Use addOnTabSelectedListener  instead of setOnTabSelectedListener

Comment: @EleojasmilJMilagrosa, @Min2 : you can only add an `instance of TabItem` via `addView` method mentioned.

Comment: does tabLayout.scrollTo() work from a OnScrollListener?

Comment: i have tablayout with width = "match parent" and i'm setting up four tabs,but it doesn't cover up all space in width and remains space at last,please help me.

Comment: Ohk,so i just fixed it by setting 'app:tabMode="fixed"' in place of app:tabMode="scrollable" in xml and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution to the accepted answer using `Tab.getPosition` rather than `TabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition` method.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Toast.makeText(
            MainActivity.this, "Tab " + tab.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    }
});
```