# Making a Custom RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-radiobutton, android-chips

I'm trying to make a custom RadioButton like this:

[image: RadioButton]

I tried making a RadioGroup with three RadioButton in it with the background of the RadioGroup being a rectangle and the background of the RadioButton would be a blue rectangle when checked and white when not but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/Frequency"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/radiorectangle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.614">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Dailyrb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Daily" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Weekly"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Weekly" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Monthly"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Monthly" />
</RadioGroup>
```

The Button

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/clearBlue">
        </solid>
        <corners android:radius="16dp"></corners>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white">
        </solid>
        <corners android:radius="16dp"></corners>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: This is not exactly a solution just a easy way. I think you can achieve this behavior with `Tablayout` .See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646586/tablayout-without-using-viewpager) . And it will work like a Group . Try it out .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this solution :

Create two shape states :

`res/drawable/state_checked.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="16dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

`res/drawable/state_unchecked.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFF">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="16dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

Then define selector for both text and background color.

Create a `text_selector.xml` in your `res/drawable/` folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" 
          android:color="#FFFFFF" /> <!-- text color when checked -->
    <item android:color="#000000" /> <!-- default text color-->
</selector>
```

Create a `background_selector.xml` in your `res/drawable/` folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_checked" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Finally, add backgroud selectr and text selector :

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/Dailyrb"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:checked="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:text="Daily" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/Weekly"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Weekly" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/Monthly"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Monthly" />
```

See the result :

[image: First Pick]
[image: Second pick]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default [**`ChipGroup`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md#chipgroup) included in the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

```
   <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            app:singleSelection="true"
            ....>

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                app:checkedIconVisible="true"
                android:text="Daily"
                .../>

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                app:checkedIconVisible="true"
                android:text="Weekly"
                .../>

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
                app:checkedIconVisible="true"
                android:text="Monthly"
                .../>

   </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

[image]