# Is there anyway to swap or reorder fragment BackStack entry?

Tags: android, android-fragments, instance, fragment-backstack

am creating multiple fragment app, which require easy changing of fragment tabs, whose BackStack entry must be kept. On user click fragment must be pop up immediate. I think reordering BackStack is the best option. Do anyone know how to reorder BackStack ?

I have 5 fragments A,B,C,D,E. if user open fragment like A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E . using default back stack,back key it works fine. But when user opens A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E ---> B. After this if user click back, default back stack will goes to A.

Comment: how about use show/hide fragment instead of push them to back stack ?

Comment: show and hide not working, thats why i thought about this

Comment: How's your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use non-swipable viewpager and on addOnPageChangeListener create arraylist and save all pages that opened. onBackPressed will compare arraylist and show pages.

Answer (score 1):

There is no api for this usecase, but there are other means to do so:

### Example

[FragmentBackStackModifyActivity](https://gist.github.com/jankovd/9303738)

Comment: but its for removing fragment from back stack not swaping or reordering, and id is based on index of add

Answer (score 0):

The user follows the path `A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E` then he wants to come to `B`. So what you should do is:

- check if `B` is already in the back stack or not.
- If it is there, then `popBackStackImmediate` to return to `B`
- If it is not there, then add the fragment `B` normally.

So replace fragment should be something like this:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    String fragmentTag =  fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName(); //unique name for the fragment, which will be used as tag.

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean isPopped = fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate(fragmentTag, 0); // trying to return to the previous state of B if it exists.

    if (!isPopped && fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){ // fragment is not in the backstack, so create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment, fragmentTag);
        ft.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Remember, this will return to the **previous state** of `B`.

TIP: Since you don't want two instances of any fragment, So try to create a singleton instance of them. Because, if you are creating a new instance of the fragment and that fragment already exists in the back stack then the new instance will be ignored (because you are returning to the previous state).

Comment: my issue is that, when back to fragment B above fragment stack will losses

Comment: @BincyBaby Yes, if the stack is `A ---> B ---> C ---> D ---> E` and then you open `B`, the stack will change to `A ---> B`.

Comment: but i want to keep it in stack other c,d,e if tab changed.

Comment: You can't go to some middle node in a `stack` without popping all the top nodes. That violates `stack` property.

If you are implementing tabs, then you should use `ViewPager`. :)

Comment: You can achieve that. Just link the ViewPager with tabs and [disable the swipe gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9650265/2720553).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123828/discussion-between-bincy-baby-and-rohit-arya).

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try this...

> onBackpressed

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {


  Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
  if (f instanceof FragmentE)
{
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);


} else if (f instanceof FragmentD) {

 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-2).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

}

else if (f instanceof FragmentC) {

 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-3).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

}

else if (f instanceof FragmentB) {

 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
   fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-4).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

}
   else
{
        super.onBackPressed();

 }
}
```

> for back remove stack

```
 final android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new android.app.FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {

            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ==0) {
               // dLayout.closeDrawers();
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
               // dLayout.closeDrawers();

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

May be  call addToBackstack() only when the fragment is  not added before

Suppose as in your case when user is in Fragment E and when user calls Fragment B check if the  Fragment B is already added in back stack

if yes, Then dont call addToBackstack for that FragmentTransaction.

else ,call addToBackstack()

check my sample code:

```
 private void addFragment (Fragment fragment){
        boolean isFragment=false;
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        for(int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
            Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId());
            if(fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getId().equalsIgnoreCase(FragmentB))// check if fragment is in back stack
            {
                isFragment=true;
            }
        }

        if (!isFragment){ //fragment added to back stack, create it.
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, FragmentB).addToBackStack(FragmentB).commit();
        }else {//else dont call addToBackStack()
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, FragmentB).commit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place this code in your MainActivity

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            //super.onBackPressed();

            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
                finish();
            }
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
```

Here `getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0` will checks that whether the stack entry is at 0 or not, if it's on 0 then the Activity will be finished.

In your case A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> B

A will be on 0, 
B will be on 1, 
C on 2, 
D on 3, 
E on 4, 
B on 5

So when you click on back, the `if` condition will checks that the backstack count is on 0.