# Android emulator and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-viewpager

I use `ViewPager` for a wizard flow in the application and I want to disable page switches from any user input ([How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)).

Recently I discovered that when I run the application in an emulator I can still swipe page with PC keyboard left and right arrow keys.

Can I disable it? Is it a real event that can happen on a real device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't reproduce your issue in a `ViewPager` based project running on the emulator, but since your already extending the `ViewPager`, you can try overriding the method below to ignore the right and left keypresses.

Untested:

```
 @Override
   public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

      switch( keyCode ) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
```

I would imagine that this is possible on hardware if the user has a physical keyboard connected.

**Update**

Try this in your extended class:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    switch( event.getAction() ) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Try a adding a breakpoint in ViewPager.executeKeyEvent before the arrowScroll() calls.  If it breaks there, check the call stack to see where is the best spot to override the event.

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly `executeKeyEvent` with `DPAD_*`