# Android disable swappable view pager

Tags: android

i'm trying to disable and enable view pager swappable programical, but on my below code multiple swipe on view pager, disable/enable feature dont work

```
public static void changeSwappableViewPagerStatus(ViewPagerCustomDuration viewPager, boolean status) {
    if (status) {
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(null);
    } else {
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: DId you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38705505/5733111)

Comment: @Sanoop that use on class extended from viewpager, like with widget

Comment: Can you post your Activity code where you are implementing this fucntion?

Comment: @Sanoop my activity have multiple fragment and i'm using `EventBus` for disable/enable view pager on parent activity by this code: `@Subscribe
    public void onEvent(EventChangeMainApplicationSwappableViewPagerStatus event) {
        AndroidUtilities.changeSwappableViewPagerStatus(viewPager, event.isStatus());
    }`

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you should make a subclass of viewpager like following and do it in onTouchEvent:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.Scroller;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setMyScroller();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

//down one is added for smooth scrolling

private void setMyScroller() {
    try {
        Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
        Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
    public MyScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
    }
}
}
```

complete resource:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9650884/6790308

Comment: using widget like with your code is not useful for my application, i'm trying to use java code to disable or enable that