# How to stop navigation if user not authenticate in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android fragments. I have 3 tabs, first one is for authentication and next 2 are used for some other info which requires a user authentication in  first tab to visit these tabs. I am not getting this how can I stop navigating to other fragments until user authentication is performed. I have sample code:

```
public class SiteSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SiteSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return authFragment;
            case 1:
                return siteInfoFragment;
            case 2:
                return userInfoFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Auth";
            case 1:
                return "Site info";
            case 2:
                return "user info";
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

In main activity class OnCreate method have like this:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.siteContainer);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });


 @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }
```

Start of application is showing Authfragment first. When user authenticates in this fragment, I have a application in which I am adding a status flag `isUserAuthenticate=true;`

I am confused on which step I should check that if isUserAuthenticate is true then let him go for next fragment otherwise stop and remain on auth fragment. Can someone give me hint or example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make **non-swipeable ViewPager**:

Here is your reference:[How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)