# Disable View Pager swipe of Viewpager in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-viewpager, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, I have View Pager in fragment and i have set pager adapter on it. everything is working fine but when i try to stop my view pager paging swipe in Kotlin and can't find any method to do so in Kotlin.
I tried to find solution on stack but no luck. Although there are many in java but not for Kotlin.

I have done this using Java as

```
viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

but whenever i try this in Kotlin i end up with error.
Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: you need to create custom view page for that

Comment: you mean i cant use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

Comment: No i dont want to do so in java.. i want help in Kotlin

Comment: please read question carefully.

Comment: you have to create a custom view pager that extends   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

Comment: I dont want solutions in java.. i Am asking how to do this in Kotlin.

Comment: why can't you take the code in the links already commented by others and convert it to kotlin yourself

Comment: @Raghunandan right

Comment: @Kriti check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392198/8112541

Comment: Whatever you can do in Java, you can also do in Kotlin. You call all the same classes and methods.

Comment: @Prem thanks.. Custom View pager was all i need to create .. Same as in java.. Thanks!!

Comment: @Kriti happy to help you

Comment: @Kriti try this like this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392198/8112541   return true for ViewPager in kotlin i think it will work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UPDATE

As of 2020 we now have [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2). If you [migrate](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration) to ViewPager2 there is a built in method to disable swiping: `myViewPager2.isUserInputEnabled = false`

---

If you're not using ViewPager2 then continue with the old answer:

I created a Kotlin version based on converting this answer from Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13437997/8023278

There is no built in way to disable swiping between pages of a ViewPager, what's required is an extension of ViewPager that overrides onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent to prevent the swiping action. To make it more generalised we can add a method setSwipePagingEnabled to enable/disable swiping between pages.

```
class SwipeLockableViewPager(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attrs) {
    private var swipeEnabled = false

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return when (swipeEnabled) {
            true -> super.onTouchEvent(event)
            false -> false
        }
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return when (swipeEnabled) {
            true -> super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
            false -> false
        }
    }

    fun setSwipePagingEnabled(swipeEnabled: Boolean) {
        this.swipeEnabled = swipeEnabled
    }
}
```

Then in our layout xml we use our new SwipeLockableViewPager instead of the standard ViewPager

```
<mypackage.SwipeLockableViewPager 
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Now in our activity/fragment we can call `myViewPager.setSwipePagingEnabled(false)` and users won't be able to swipe between pages

Answer (score 1):

In ViewPager2 only following code snippet is sufficient :

```
viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
```