# Quit swipe in viewPager in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager, swipe

I made a little app to control a sticker album, it has 3 tabs and a FragmentPagerAdapter and works perflectly, but I want quit the swip effect, I only want that it works clicking on tabs.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zq1g.png)

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

Comment: I have a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: Are you not using the FragmentPagerAdapter in a ViewPager? If yes, the solution is telling you to use custom(subclass) ViewPager and override the touch events you don't want.