# Disable swipe the viewPager in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

**What I did**

Made a class **CustomViewPager** that makes swipe disable. However I can't use it correctly with using **androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager**.　Display about ViewPager disappeared.

**Code**

AdapterViewPager.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using AndroidX.Fragment.App;
using AndroidX.ViewPager.Widget;
using Fragment = AndroidX.Fragment.App.Fragment;

namespace Android
{
//NuGet
//ViewPageAdapter
//lifecycle
public class VPAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private bool m_enabled;

    List<Fragment> fragments = new List<Fragment>();
    List<string> fragmentsName = new List<string>();

    public VPAdapter(AndroidX.Fragment.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager) : base(fragmentManager)
    {
        fragments = new List<Fragment>();
        fragmentsName = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, string name)
    {
        fragments.Add(fragment);
        fragmentsName.Add(name);
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return fragments.Count;
        }

    }

    public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        return fragments[position];
    }

    public void SetPagingEnabled(bool enabled)
    {
        m_enabled = enabled;
    }
}

public class CustomViewPager : ViewPager
{
    public bool ScrollEnabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.ScrollEnabled = false;
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (this.ScrollEnabled)
        {
            return base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (this.ScrollEnabled)
        {
            return base.OnInterceptTouchEvent(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void SetPagingEnabled(bool enabled)
    {
        ScrollEnabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

}

ActivityMain.cs

```
//ViewPager
VPAdapter vpAdapter = new VPAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
//omission
viewPager.Adapter = vpAdapter;

//CustomViewpager
private IAttributeSet attrs;
CustomViewPager customViewPager2 = new CustomViewPager(this, attrs);
customViewPager2.SetPagingEnabled(false);
```

activity_main.xml

```
                <Android.CustomViewPager
                 android:id="@+id/customViewPager" 
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">
                    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
                </SMP_Android.CustomViewPager>
```

**Reference destination**

[Is there a way to disable the swiping between Tabbed Page on Android in Xamarin Native android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598088/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-swiping-between-tabbed-page-on-android-in-xamarin)

[How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just replace standard ViewPager with your custom one. No need to put the standard one inside the custom. That's all you need:

```
<SMP_Android.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```