# MPAndroidChart - Linechart horizontal scrolling in ViewPager - Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, mpandroidchart

I have a ViewPager with more pages and on every page is LineChart (width = match_parent). If user scrolls to the end of the first chart, next when he scrolls again I want to start showing the next chart (like ViewPager change page). But if the user is in the middle of the chart then he should scroll only in the chart itself (not between pages in the ViewPager).

I'm trying override `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` of the ViewPager but it still not working good...

I also found this: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1885 but there is not a solution...

Do you have some suggestion?

Comment: can you add your design here

Comment: @hasan_shaikh What exactly you mean with design? Layout is simple. I have a ViewPager and every page/fragment has one LineChart (width is match parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable viewpager scroll view and use gesture detector for swipe left and right. MPAndroidchart have builtin horizontal scroll for line chart try its listener.

Comment: Can you send me some example? How should I disable viewpager scroll view? Please try to provide more info.

Comment: For diabling view pager skype try this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s