# Disable ViewPager Swipe

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm in a class extending a FragmentActivity. To disable the viewpager swipe i wan't to override the onInterceptTouchEvent method which is not possible because i can't extend the viewpager class because i'm already extending the FragmentActivity class.

A solution for this problem would be to create a custom viewpager:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager
{
    private boolean enabled;
    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return this.enabled && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

and

```
 CustomViewPager viewPager;
 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

but then i get the following casting error:

> android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to MainPage$CustomViewPager

are there some other ways to override the onInterceptTouchEvent method or to disable the view pager swipe?

Comment: Which casting error? Any helpful errors or logcat would be great to add in here. Thank you. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write;

```
viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
```

The findViewById method returns view, you have to say which class will be initialized.

Comment: This is not working. It says that (CustomViewPager) is redundant and i get the same cast error:  android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to MainPage$CustomViewPager

Comment: Change ViewPager tag in xml file with your custom class including package name.

Comment: Thanks "Change ViewPager tag in xml file with your custom class including package name" worked.