# How to disable swiping in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

Is it possible to enable-disable swiping in new android [`viewpager2`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) component?

Answer (score 361, accepted):

Now it is possible to enable-disable swiping `viewpager2` using `Version 1.0.0-alpha02`

Use **`implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha02'`**

> [**Version 1.0.0**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#version_100_3)

**New features**

- Ability to disable user input (`setUserInputEnabled`, `isUserInputEnabled`)

**API changes**

- `ViewPager2` class final

**Bug fixes**

- `FragmentStateAdapter` stability fixes

**SAMPLE CODE to disable swiping in viewpager2**

```
myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

**SAMPLE CODE to enable swiping in viewpager2**

```
myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Perfect. Now I can have a map fragment and scroll it and use swiping for the other fragments.

Comment: Does this also disable tapping on the tabs to change the current tab to another specific tab?

Comment: is there a way to do this using xml?

Comment: @aLL there is no way to do this using XML at the moment

Answer (score 17):

If you are using Android Data Binding you can simply disable it your layout xml file.

```
app:userInputEnabled="@{false}"
```

Answer (score 13):

```
viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

Under the hood `ViewPager2` works with `RecyclerView` for inflating the fragment views, but the `RecyclerView` is hidden so they make it more idiot proof.

```
 val rv : RecyclerView = viewPager.getChildAt(0) as RecyclerView
 rv.layoutManager = NonScrollingLayoutManager( rv.context, rv.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager)
```

Hacky way is to get the child at position zero which is the `RecyclerView` and disable  scrolling in the layout manager, by wrapping the layout manager:

```
inner class NonScrollingLayoutManager(context: Context, val layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager) :
    LinearLayoutManager(context, layoutManager.orientation, layoutManager.reverseLayout) {

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean  = layoutManager.orientation == HORIZONTAL


    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean  =  layoutManager.orientation == VERTICAL

}
```

Please beware that if the API changes the layout manager used for the RecyclerView, i.e they move away from the `LinearLayoutManager` this wont work and it will need some methods overriden and ensure super methods are called.

Second approach is subclass the `ViewPager2` which is `ViewGroup` and then do the magic in intercepting touch events, before they are dispatched to the child views (as you would guess the `RecyclerView`) and be careful not to prevent clicks.

Comment: subclass is impossible because viewPages2 is final.

Comment: @Guy At the time my answer was posted ViewPager2 was open.

Comment: Sorry but creating a separate class just this is bad practice. Kotlin and VP2 offer this short one-liner `pager.userInputEnabled = false`

Answer (score 6):

You can use in Kotlin like this

```
 viewPager2.isUserInputEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

`mViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);` //disables swipe

`mViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);` //enables swipe

We can disable and enable based on tabs, as shown in below code

```
ViewPager2 mViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        mViewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        mViewPager2.setAdapter(adapter); 


        TabLayout tabLayout  = findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //do stuff here
                if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                    **//ToDisable**
                    mViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    **//ToEnable**
                    mViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(true);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use `myViewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false); // in java myViewPager2.isUserInputEnabled = false // in kotlin`
to disable manually scrolling by user on swiping