# ViewPager2 disable swipe action

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, swipe, android-viewpager2

I'm using the new `ViewPager2` in a project and I need to disable the swipe action. Have to restrict the user to change tabs only pressing the `TabLayout` buttons.

With the default `ViewPager` you can achieve this by making your custom `ViewPager` and `Override` the `onTouchEvent` method but this is not an option for `ViewPager2` because it's final and you can't inherit it.

Before changing back to `ViewPager` I wanna know if is there any way to do this using `ViewPager2`

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978846/how-to-disable-swiping-in-viewpager2/55193815#55193815 ?

Comment: @NileshRathod Yea that solved it. Thank you!