# How To Disable Swiping In View Pager When Using FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I Am Having Many Tabs And Single `TabViewPagerAdapter` Which Is Extended By `FragmentPagerAdapter` As Shown Below,

```
package com.example.newsline.Adapters;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private boolean swipable;

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}


public TabViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mFragmentList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

}
```

Now I Want TO Disable Left and Right Swiping Tabs Must Only Be Changed When Clicked On It. Below Is My Activity,

```
package com.example.newsline.Activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.newsline.Adapters.NewsCardAdapter;
import com.example.newsline.Adapters.TabViewPagerAdapter;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.AhmedabadFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.AjabGajabFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.BollyWoodFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.BusinessFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.DharmDarshanFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.GadgetsFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.GujratFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.InternationalFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.NRGFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.NationalFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.RajkotFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.RasdharFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.RecipesFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.SportsFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.SuratFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.TopNewsFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Fragments.VadodaraFragment;
import com.example.newsline.Model.NewsModel;
import com.example.newsline.R;
import com.example.newsline.Utils.URLs;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipeDecor;
import com.mindorks.placeholderview.SwipePlaceHolderView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "NewsActivity";
Context context;


ProgressDialog progress;

private TabViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private ViewPager pager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    context = this;

    progress = new ProgressDialog(context, 
R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    progress.setMessage("Loading News...Please Wait! ");
    progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progress.setIndeterminate(true);
    progress.setCancelable(false);
    progress.show();

    customActionBar();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_news_activity);
    setUpViewPager(pager);

    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);



}

private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager pager) {

    adapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new AjabGajabFragment(), "Ajab-Gajab");
    adapter.addFragment(new BollyWoodFragment(), "Bollywood");
    adapter.addFragment(new BusinessFragment(), "Business");
    adapter.addFragment(new DharmDarshanFragment(), "Dharm Darshan");
    adapter.addFragment(new GadgetsFragment(), "Gadgets");
    adapter.addFragment(new GujratFragment(), "Gujrat");
    adapter.addFragment(new InternationalFragment(), "International");
    adapter.addFragment(new NationalFragment(), "National");
    adapter.addFragment(new NRGFragment(), "NRG");
    adapter.addFragment(new RajkotFragment(), "Rajkot");
    adapter.addFragment(new RasdharFragment(), "Rasdhar");
    adapter.addFragment(new RecipesFragment(), "Recipes");
    adapter.addFragment(new SportsFragment(), "Sports");
    adapter.addFragment(new SuratFragment(), "Surat");
    adapter.addFragment(new TopNewsFragment(), "Top News");
    adapter.addFragment(new VadodaraFragment(), "Vadodara");


    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    progress.cancel();
} 

public void customActionBar() {

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(NewsActivity.this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_new_activity, null);

    bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    bar.setCustomView(view);

    ImageView ivCategories = (ImageView) 
view.findViewById(R.id.iv_categories);
    ivCategories.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Create a Custom viewPager with set onInterceptTouchEvent is false 

For example follow this below code 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: @AravindV Thank You, But Can It Be Done With The Code I Already Have??

Comment: then what was the issue

Comment: Solved It With The Example You Provided, Thank You.