# How to disable swiping with finger to detach a RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have implemented an Overlay view... currently the view is detachable by edge swiping from left to right (like paging). I would like to prevent this. How can I do that?

I have tried the method recommended in [How do disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager but still be able to swipe programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s/13392198) to disable paging by swiping with finger in ViewPager. However, it didn't help my case.

This is how I inflate my view,

```
private void initView() {
        if (null == mInflater) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (null == mscreenView) {
            mscreenView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_screen, null);
        }
    }
```

My `view_screen.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_background_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/screen_background_status_dummy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/screen_background_in_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/screen_background_status_dummy"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/screen_background_image"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/"
                android:contentDescription="@string/background_image" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.xyz.screenusingservice.ScreenView
        android:id="@+id/screen_forground_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/screen_forground_status_dummy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/screen_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/black_with_logo" />
    </com.xyz.screenusingservice.ScreenView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `ScreenView.java`

```
public class ScreenView extends RelativeLayout {
    private Context mActivityContext = null;
    private final String TAG = "screenView";
    private static final String SCREEN_WINDOW_HIDDEN = "com.route1.screenusingservice.WINDOW_HIDDEN";

    public static boolean isWindowDetached = true;

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, @Nullable Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        Log.d(TAG, "Full screen view onFocusChanged");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow () {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        isWindowDetached = true;
        screen.setServiceStopped(true);
        Log.e(TAG, "Fullscreen view onDetachedFromWindow");
        screen screen = screen.getInstance(mActivityContext);
        if (null != screen) { //TODO find a better solution to stop the service
                screen.stopscreenService();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptHoverEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        //requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onScrollChanged");
    }



    @Override
    public void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        isWindowDetached = false;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.screen_image );
        if(null != imageView) {
            imageView.invalidate();
            Bitmap bitmap = screen.getBitmap();
            if (bitmap != null) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    bitmap = makeTransparent(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                    if (null != bitmap) {
                        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        //imageView.background
                        BitmapDrawable ob = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                        imageView.setBackground(ob);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert transparentColor to be transparent in a Bitmap.
    public Bitmap makeTransparent(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {

        int [] allpixels = new int [ bitmap.getHeight()*bitmap.getWidth()];
        bitmap.getPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
        List<Rect> rectList = screen.getTransparentCoordinates();
        if(rectList != null) {
            for (Rect rect : rectList) {
                rect = getValidRect(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), rect);
                if (rect != null) {
                    for (int i = rect.left; i < rect.right; i++) {
                        for (int j = rect.top; j < rect.bottom; j++) {
                            allpixels[i + j * width] = Color.alpha(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        bitmap.setPixels(allpixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        return bitmap;
    }




    public Rect getValidRect(Rect destRect, Rect srcRect){
        //return (rect.left >= 0 && rect.right >= 0 && rect.width() <=viewPortWidth && rect.height() <= viewPortHeight)
        if(!destRect.contains(srcRect)) {
            boolean isInterSected = srcRect.setIntersect(srcRect, destRect);
            if(!isInterSected){
                return new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        return srcRect;
    }


    public ScreenView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mActivityContext = context;
        initView();
    }

    public ScreenView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mActivityContext = context;
        initView();
    }

    public ScreenView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mActivityContext = context;
        initView();
    }

    @TargetApi(21)
    public ScreenView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        mActivityContext = context;
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
    }

}
```

My activity `onCreate` method,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        sscreenActivityContext = this;
        mMainHandler = new SendMassgeHandler();
        getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        } else {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }        
    }
```