# How can I stop the screen from being able to slide (viewpager) with a button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I don't have any specific code for this, since I'm not sure how to approach it. Basically I want to be able to slide the screen when swiped, but I want to stop the screen from sliding when I press a specific button. I'm trying to make a game and the tutorial would involve slides to explain it, but I want a button at the last slide to start the game and the end the tutorial. If I leave it as is, the player could swipe left and go back to the tutorial, which would be weird. How should I do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed the viewpager's visibility to *"gone"* after the **end tutorial** button click?

Alternatively, you could look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s) to see how to disable viewpager's swipe functionality.

A whole another approach would be to take the tutorial to another level - you could use DialogFragment with a custom view to do that.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! I didn't know that was an option!

Comment: Just make sure to make changes to view only on UI thread, otherwise the app will crash. Just use Activity.runOnUiThread method when you change the visibility of a View. I still believe that a DialogFragment would be a better option for what you are trying to do, though.